# How to decompile DEX into Java source code?

Tags: java, android, reverse-engineering, decompiler, dex

How can one decompile Android DEX (VM bytecode) files into corresponding Java source code?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2009/01/disassembling-dex-files.html).
You will get possible leads from there to move on.

Comment: Updated info is available on coders hub blog: http://www.coders-hub.com/2013/04/how-to-convert-apk-file-into-source.html

Comment: If you have money, buy [jeb](https://www.pnfsoftware.com/), otherwise use [jadx](https://github.com/skylot/jadx), see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28864945/3739455) why

Comment: There is a new cross plateform (java) and open source tool, that enable you to do that, just checkout bytecodeviewer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36557898/795245

Answer (score 977, accepted):

## It's easy

Get these tools:

1. [dex2jar](https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar) to translate dex files to jar files
2. [jd-gui](http://jd.benow.ca/) to view the java files in the jar

The source code is quite readable as dex2jar makes some optimizations.

### Procedure:

And here's the procedure on how to decompile:

#### Step 1:

Convert classes.dex in test_apk-debug.apk to test_apk-debug_dex2jar.jar

```
d2j-dex2jar.sh -f -o output_jar.jar apk_to_decompile.apk
d2j-dex2jar.sh -f -o output_jar.jar dex_to_decompile.dex
```

> **Note 1:** In the Windows machines all the `.sh` scripts are replaced by `.bat` scripts

> **Note 2:** On linux/mac don't forget about `sh` or `bash`. The full command should be:

```
sh d2j-dex2jar.sh -f -o output_jar.jar apk_to_decompile.apk
```

> **Note 3:** Also, remember to add execute permission to `dex2jar-X.X` directory e.g. `sudo chmod -R +x dex2jar-2.0`

[dex2jar documentation](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/wiki/ModifyApkWithDexTool)

#### Step 2:

Open the jar in JD-GUI

[image: The decompiled source]

Comment: +1. I tried both Baksmali and Dex2jar. Dex2Jar+JD-Gui wins for giving you perfectly readable source code for most .dex files.

Comment: hi, Will you please share the way you are going? I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: The code I got back from JD-GUI was very odd (some activities were split up into multiple activities like Activity$1 Activity$2 etc). It took a little work to unscramble, but much less than starting all over!

Comment: The above sentence rang a bell - it seems to be a semi-quote from here: http://geeknizer.com/decompile-reverse-engineer-android-apk/ (or the other way around?). The linked articles briefly explains the above mentioned tools as well as Smali and APKTool.

Comment: @JonathanDumaine that depends. If the JARs are obfuscated and you want to do little modifications, Backsmali is the only way to go. **Bonus!** With APKTool you also get all the XMLs, images and other resources back. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8792985/710951).

Comment: @JonathanDumaine I agree with jmendeth, apktool is also the way to go if you want to decompile your apk, modify it and then recompile it.
While using dex2jar and jd-gui the source are really readable but you can't recompile whitout some errors!

Comment: If you don't like using jd-gui for the interface, you can follow instructions to save the java file hierarchy to a folder of your choice: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1384652/198348

Comment: why do you need the step 1? when you can just rename the .apk to .zip and open?
But yes 2nd step is required as it is in compiled classes and we need to decompile to source code

Comment: @JonathanDumaine well it's 2019 and **Dex2Jar+JD-Gui** sometimes fails to convert whole class files. Even earlier it could get convert all files and all parts of file. So **BAKSMALI** should be better. You need **BAKSMALI/SMALI** anyway if want to made some patches to applicaiton. **Dex2Jar+JD-Gui** is just for reading (to try understand at least something of source code), not patching

Comment: I'm sorry I mistakenly downvoted this answer and I tried to reverse it but failed. I wanted to up-vote the answer but ended up voting it down due to a technical or hardware issue(Sensor problem) with my phone. **The answer is really helpful**

Comment: Is it possible to use dex2jar directly inside Android app ? Meaning I develop an Android app that uses it?

Answer (score 143):

To clarify somewhat, there are two major paths you might take here depending on what you want to accomplish:

Decompile the Dalvik bytecode (dex) into readable Java source. You can do this easily with [dex2jar](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) and [jd-gui](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui), as fred mentions. The resulting source is useful to read and understand the functionality of an app, but will likely not produce 100% usable code. In other words, you can read the source, but you can't really modify and repackage it. Note that if the source has been obfuscated with proguard, the resulting source code will be substantially more difficult to untangle.

The other major alternative is to disassemble the bytecode to [smali](http://code.google.com/p/smali/), an assembly language designed for precisely this purpose. I've found that the easiest way to do this is with [apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/). Once you've got apktool installed, you can just point it at an apk file, and you'll get back a smali file for each class contained in the application. You can read and modify the smali or even replace classes entirely by generating smali from new Java source (to do this, you could compile your .java source to .class files with javac, then convert your .class files to .dex files with Android's dx compiler, and then use baksmali (smali disassembler) to convert the .dex to .smali files, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448267/direct-java-to-smali-conversion-possible). There might be a shortcut here). Once you're done, you can easily package the apk back up with apktool again. Note that apktool does not sign the resulting apk, so you'll need to take care of that [just like any other Android application](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html).

If you go the smali route, you might want to try [APK Studio](http://www.vaibhavpandey.com/apkstudio/), an IDE that automates some of the above steps to assist you with decompiling and recompiling an apk and installing it on a device.

In short, your choices are pretty much either to decompile into Java, which is more readable but likely irreversible, or to disassemble to smali, which is harder to read but much more flexible to make changes and repackage a modified app. Which approach you choose would depend on what you're looking to achieve.

Lastly, the suggestion of [dare](http://siis.cse.psu.edu/dare/index.html) is also of note. It's a retargeting tool to convert .dex and .apk files to java .class files, so that they can be analyzed using typical java static analysis tools.

Comment: try APK Studio, was an amazing choice

Answer (score 62):

I'd actually recommend going here:
https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali

It provides BAKSMALI, which is a most excellent reverse-engineering tool for DEX files.
It's made by JesusFreke, the guy who created the fameous ROMs for Android.

Comment: smali is an assembly-like language based on dalvik IL, it cannot be directly translated to Java.

Comment: @endryha There are no tools capable of doing that. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582824/decompile-smali-files-on-an-apk) for more info.

Comment: Code, code, code, ... Why only code? If you use APKTool you get _everything_ back! And it's as simple as `./apktool d myprogram.apk`. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8792985/710951).

Answer (score 42):

Since `Dheeraj Bhaskar`'s answer is relatively old as many years past.

Here is my latest (2019 year) answer:

## Main Logic

from `dex` to `java sourcecode`, currently has two kind of solution:

- `One Step`: directly convert `dex` to `java sourcecode`
- `Two Step`: first convert `dex` to `jar`, second convert `jar` to `java sourcecode`

---

## One step solution: `dex` directly to `java sourcecode`

### Tools

- [jadx](https://github.com/skylot/jadx)

### Process

1. download [jadx-0.9.0.zip](https://github.com/skylot/jadx/releases/download/v0.9.0/jadx-0.9.0.zip), unzip it, in `bin` folder can see command line `jadx` or GUI version `jadx-gui`, double click to run GUI version: `jadx-gui`

[image]

2. open `dex` file

[image]

then can show java source code:

[image]

3. `File` -> `save as gradle project`

[image]

then got java sourcecode:

[image]

---

## Two Step solution

### Step1: `dex` to `jar`

#### Tools

- [dex2jar](https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar)

#### Process

download [dex2jar zip](https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar/releases), unzip got `d2j-dex2jar.sh`, then:

- `apk` to `jar`: `sh d2j-dex2jar.sh -f ~/path/to/apk_to_decompile.apk`
- `dex` to `jar`: `sh d2j-dex2jar.sh -f ~/path/to/dex_to_decompile.dex`

example:

```
➜  v3.4.8 /Users/crifan/dev/dev_tool/android/reverse_engineering/dex-tools/dex-tools-2.1-SNAPSHOT/d2j-dex2jar.sh -f com.huili.readingclub8825612.dex
dex2jar com.huili.readingclub8825612.dex -> ./com.huili.readingclub8825612-dex2jar.jar
➜  v3.4.8 ll
-rw-------  1 crifan  staff   9.5M  3 21 10:00 com.huili.readingclub8825612-dex2jar.jar
-rw-------  1 crifan  staff   8.4M  3 19 14:04 com.huili.readingclub8825612.dex
```

### Step2: `jar` to `java sourcecode`

#### Tools

- [jd-gui](http://java-decompiler.github.io): most popular, but `many` code will decompile error
- [CRF](http://www.benf.org/other/cfr/): popular, `minor` code will decompile error
- **[Procyon](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon)**: popular, `no` code decompile error

  - GUI tool based on `Procyon`

    - [Luyten](https://github.com/deathmarine/Luyten):
    - [Bytecode Viewer](https://github.com/Konloch/bytecode-viewer)
- others

  - [Krakatau](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau)
  - [Fernflower](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins/java-decompiler/engine)
  - old one: [AndroChef](http://www.androiddecompiler.com/)
  - etc.

#### Process

here demo `Procyon` convert jar to java source code:

download [procyon-decompiler-0.5.34.jar](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/downloads/procyon-decompiler-0.5.34.jar)

then using syntax:

`java -jar /path/to/procyon-decompiler-0.5.34.jar -jar your_to_decompile.jar -o outputFolderName`

example:

`java -jar  /Users/crifan/dev/dev_tool/android/reverse_engineering/Procyon/procyon-decompiler-0.5.34.jar -jar com.huili.readingclub8825612-dex2jar.jar -o com.huili.readingclub8825612`

using editor [VSCode](https://book.crifan.org/books/best_editor_vscode/website/) to open exported source code, look like this:

[image]

## Conclusion

Conversion correctness : `Jadx` > `Procyon` > `CRF` > `JD-GUI`

Recommend use: (One step solution's) `Jadx`

---

for more detailed explanation, please refer my online **Chinese** ebook: [安卓应用的安全和破解](https://book.crifan.org/books/android_app_security_crack/website/)

Comment: strange, but if I try to execute 1 step (dex to jar decompile on Windows) via this command `dex2jar-2.0>d2j-dex2jar.bat -f D:\android\some_dex_file.dex` just got exception: `java.io.IOException: the src file not a .dex or zip file`

Comment: @Сергей could you try : `d2j-dex2jar.bat "D:\android\some_dex_file.dex"` is ok or not ?

Comment: yes, I tried exactly `>d2j-dex2jar.bat  file.dex` but it's not ok. maybe it's because my `.dex` file was copied from `dalvik-cache` ?

Comment: @Сергей yes, the most possible reason is your said `dex is copied from dalvik-cache`, should be `dex is decompiled from apk`

Comment: @crifan, thanks for this answer. JADX is impressive. i'll back to work. Emmanuel@JD-Gui

Comment: as on 27 aug 2020, jadx-gui supports direct apk file(even without extracting dex from it first). its an open source project, so community making it better and better.

Comment: I will write my own who knows you maybe a CCP person.

Answer (score 32):

<sup>A more complete version of [fred](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507351/fred)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4177581/710951):</sup>

### Manual way

First you need a tool to **extract** all the (compiled) classes on the DEX to a JAR.
There's one called [dex2jar](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/), which is made by a chinese student.

Then, you can use [jd-gui](http://jd.benow.ca/) to **decompile** the classes on the JAR to source code.
The resulting source should be quite readable, as dex2jar applies some optimizations.

### Automatic way

You can use [APKTool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/). It will *automatically* extract all the classes (`.dex`), resources (`.asrc`), then it will convert *binary XML* to *human-readable XML*, and it will also  **dissassemble** the classes for you.
**Disassembly will always be more robust than decompiling, *especially* with

JARs obfuscated with Pro Guard!**

Just tell APKTool to *decode* the APK into a directory, then *modify* what you want,
and finally *encode* it back to an APK. That's all.

**Important:** APKTool **dissassembles**. It doesn't **decompile**.
The generated code won't be Java source.
But you should be able to read it, and even edit it if you're familiar with [jasmin](http://jasmin.sourceforge.net).
If you want Java source, please go over the *Manual way*.

Answer (score 26):

Sometimes you get broken code, when using `dex2jar`/`apktool`, most notably in loops. To avoid this, use [jadx](https://github.com/skylot/jadx), which decompiles dalvik bytecode into java source code, without creating a `.jar`/`.class` file first as `dex2jar` does (apktool uses dex2jar I think). It is also open-source and in active development. It even has a GUI, for GUI-fanatics. Try it!

Comment: I suppose jadx doesn't have compile option but the code is readable though

Comment: @EnesBattal you mean like `javac "$(find . -name '*.java')"` ?

Comment: how about forming an apk ? placing classes in apk, zipalign, signing etc.

Comment: @EnesBattal Well you can help implement that - otherwise you could use apktool for that.. or zipalign/sign with the android tools

Comment: This answer makes it sound like it doesn't ever use the dex2jar tool, but instead decompiles directly from dex to java source code. Is that really the case?

If so, then how is it also able to open normal desktop jar files? (just tried and it works) Does it have a separate decompiler for dex and jars?

Comment: Is it possible to use jadx inside Android itself?

Comment: Wow bro, dex2jar code was not tangible to me, but shown in jadx gui looks pretty good. It didn't even fail, unlike some Illegal exception coming with dex2jar. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

I have used

1. dex2jar + jd-gui
2. javadecompilers.com
3. enjarify
4. Apktool

But none beats google's own tools

1)**Android Studio 2.x:**
build> analyze apk
[image]

2)**Android Studio 3.0:**
Profile or Debug APK
[image]
[image]

Comment: Plus one for Enjarify. In my personal experience, it has proven to give  better results as compared to d2j

Answer (score 15):

Since no one mentioned this, there's one more tool: [DED homepage](http://siis.cse.psu.edu/ded/)

Install how-to and some explanations: [Installation](http://siis.cse.psu.edu/ded/installation.html).

It was used in a quite interesting study of the security of top market apps(not really related, just if you're curious): [A Survey of Android Application Security](http://www.enck.org/pubs/enck-sec11.pdf)

Comment: It looks promising. Does it decompile Java code directly form the APK? What about obfuscated Java code?

Answer (score 13):

Once you downloaded your APK file , You need to do the following steps to get a editable java code/document.

1. Convert your apk file to zip (while start your download don't go with "save" option , just go with "save as" and mention your extension as .zip) by doing like this you may avoid APKTOOL...
2. Extract the zip file , there you can find somefilename.dex. so now we need to convert dex -> .class
3. To do that, you need "dex2jar"(you can download it from http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/ , after extracted, in command prompt you have to mention like, **[D:\dex2jar-0.09>dex2jar somefilename.dex]** (Keep in mind that your somefilename.dex must be inside the same folder where you have keep your dex2jar.)
4. Download jad from http://www.viralpatel.net/blogs/download/jad/jad.zip and extract it. Once extracted you can see two files like "jad.exe" and "Readme.txt" (sometimes "jad.txt" may there instead of "jad.exe", so just rename its extension as.exe to run)
5. Finally, in command prompt you have to mention like **[D:\jad>jad -sjava yourfilename.class]** it will parse your class file into editable java document.

Answer (score 9):

[Android Reverse Engineering is possible](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2011/12/android-reverse-engineering-decompile.html) 
 . Follow these steps to get .java file from apk file.

**Step1 . Using dex2jar**

- Generate .jar file from .apk file
- command : `dex2jar sampleApp.apk`

**Step2 . Decompiling .jar using JD-GUI**

- it decompiles the .class files i.e., we'll get **obfuscated** .java back from the apk.

Comment: But if i compile again all the decompiled source code,it wil not run ,compiler shows a lot errors.

Comment: is there any solution available for decompile android java source code will run in eclipse

Comment: **Reverse Engineering** does _not_ necessarily mean **decompiling**. In fact, ProGuard-obfuscated JARs won't decompile correctly.

Comment: If you are dealing with Obfuscated code, it's better to just **dissassemble** it. You won't get Java source, but you _always_ will be able to see/modify the code. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8792985/710951).

Comment: I would recommend doing both decompiling and disassembling. The resulting decompiled code is easier to understand but all modifications needs to be done with disassemblied version. Especially true if proguard has been used. I find that dex2jar combined with jd-gui is the best for decompiling.

Comment: How to use JD-GUI to Decompiling .jar ??

Answer (score 8):

With [Dedexer](http://dedexer.sourceforge.net/), you can disassemble the `.dex` file into dalvik bytecode (`.ddx`).

Decompiling towards Java isn't possible as far as I know.
You can read about dalvik bytecode [here](http://www.dalvikvm.com/).

Comment: accepted since you're the one saying that it isn't (currently) possible, which seems true.

Comment: @Will everything is possible. Just depends on how you see it. Decompiling *is* possible, but maybe not the way you are thinking of.

Answer (score 6):

Recent Debian have Python package `androguard`:

```
Description-en: full Python tool to play with Android files
 Androguard is a full Python tool to play with Android files.
  * DEX, ODEX
  * APK
  * Android's binary xml
  * Android resources
  * Disassemble DEX/ODEX bytecodes
  * Decompiler for DEX/ODEX files
```

Install corresponding packages:

```
sudo apt-get install androguard python-networkx
```

Decompile DEX file:

```
$ androdd -i classes.dex -o ./dir-for-output
```

Extract `classes.dex` from Apk + Decompile:

```
$ androdd -i app.apk -o ./dir-for-output
```

Apk file is nothing more that Java archive (JAR), you may extract files from archive via:

```
$ unzip app.apk -d ./dir-for-output
```

Answer (score 5):

A lot has changed since most of these answers were posted. Now-a-days there a are many easy tools with GUI's, like these:

```
APK Easy Tool for Windows (GUI tool, friendly)
Bytecode Viewer - APK/Java Reverse Engineering Suite
URET Android Reverser Toolkit
```

Best place to find them is on the XDA Developers forum.

Answer (score 4):

You might try [JADX](https://github.com/skylot/jadx) or [Procyon](https://github.com/mstrobel/procyon/wiki), this is a perfect tool for DEX decompilation.

And yes, it is also available online on (my :0)) new site: http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk/

Comment: Say, can it be used in code instead? Meaning even in Android itself? And isn't the website here: https://github.com/skylot/jadx ?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in following five steps:

[This gem does these things for you automatically even the installation of required tools](http://www.singhajit.com/convert-apk-file-to-java-code/)

1. convert apk file to zip
2. unzip the file
3. extract classes.dex from it
4. use dex to jar to convert classes.dex into jar file
5. use jadx gui to open the jar file as java source code

Answer (score 2):

Easiest method to decompile an android app is to download an app named **ShowJava** from playstore . Just select the application that needs to be decompiled from the list of applications. There are three different decompiler you can use to decompile an app namely -

> CFR 0.110, JaDX 0.6.1 or FernFlower (analytical decompiler) .

Answer (score 1):

If you're not looking to download dex2jar, then just use the [`apk_grabber` python script](https://github.com/braebot/apk_grabber) to decompile any apk into jar files.  Then you read them with jd-gui.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned before, in 2 steps:

1. Dex2jar
2. Pick up a decompiler

I will focus on step 2.

Take a look at this research paper : [The Strengths and Behavioral Quirks of Java Bytecode Decompilers](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Cesar_Soto-Valero/publication/334465294_The_Strengths_and_Behavioral_Quirks_of_Java_Bytecode_Decompilers/links/)

Understand the strength and weaknesses of each decompiler.

1. [CFR](https://github.com/leibnitz27/cfr): Considered by many as the absolute best decompiler, its specificity is that it takes a lot a liberty in graph transformations to maximise the chance of good results, at the expense of original code ordering, and has a lot of technical settings. The last version has a line number mapping but no line number realignment.
2. [Procyon](https://github.com/mstrobel/procyon): This one has the best chances to produce well structured code, adds final keywords everywhere it can, but often adds unexpected illegal casts. It has also a GUI project [Luyten](https://github.com/deathmarine/Luyten).
3. [Fernflower](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins/java-decompiler/engine): It's the decompiler from the popular IDE Intellij Idea. It often decompiles right but code is sometimes not ideally structured and has very bad naming of exception variables var1..n.
4. [Vineflower](https://github.com/Vineflower/vineflower): It's a fork of fernflower which brings improvements and bug fixes, with a test suite borrowed to CFR.
5. [JD-GUI](https://github.com/java-decompiler/jd-gui): It's the GUI of the [JD-CORE](https://github.com/java-decompiler/jd-core) project. The new version of JD-CORE structures the code into a control flow graph and an abstract syntax tree. The previous version which was present until v1.4.2 of JD-GUI was another decompiler based on bytecode pattern matching like [JAD](http://www.kpdus.com/jad.html). JD-CORE is focused on producing a recompilable output on many open source projects and also on getting line number realignment right for a debug-ready output.
6. [JADX](https://github.com/skylot/jadx): This project looks actively maintained and promising, but for the time being, the results are not very solid.

The following GUI projects support several decompilers:

- [Recaf](https://github.com/Col-E/Recaf): provides support for the following decompilers: CFR · FernFlower · Procyon
- [Bytecodeviewer](https://github.com/Konloch/bytecode-viewer): A Java 8+ Jar & Android APK Reverse Engineering Suite (Editor, Debugger, decompilers like CFR, JD-GUI etc.)
- [JD-GUI-DUO](https://github.com/nbauma109/jd-gui-duo) : this project uses forks of JD-CORE projects and revives the old algorithm in project named [jd-core-v0](https://github.com/nbauma109/jd-core-v0) and brings improvements and bug fixes in a fork of [jd-core v1](https://github.com/nbauma109/jd-core). Also supports CFR, Procyon, Vineflower & JADX.

Also Eclipse plugins are worth mentioning:

- [ECD](https://github.com/ecd-plugin/ecd) and this [fork](https://github.com/nbauma109/ecd)
- [JD-Eclipse](https://github.com/java-decompiler/jd-eclipse) and this [fork](https://github.com/nbauma109/jd-eclipse)

See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78249357/8315843)