# Decompile java class file

Tags: java, class, decompiling, decompiler

Is it possible to decompile a java .class file within another program ?
I'm aware of tools like CAVAJ and DJ Java Decompiler.
**Why ?** : I'm modifying a class file within the program and dumping it into the same. I want to then parse the source file of the modified class file.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: And why would want to do something like this?

Comment: You might be able to execute the process of running the decompiler tool (I use JD-GUI) and then edit the code and recompile? I think it is "Runtime.exec()"?

Comment: @SnakeEye I'm instrumenting the class file. After instrumenting it I want to parse the instrumented file(which I will get by decompiling the class file) in the same program.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Bucco .I'd appreciate it if you could elaborate on how I could use a GUI decompiler in  `Runtime.exec()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible answer (this is what I use for compiling source files)

```
private int runProcess(String command) throws Exception
{
    Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    System.out.println(command);
    printLines("", pro.getInputStream());
    printLines("",pro.getErrorStream());
    pro.waitFor();
    return(pro.exitValue());
}
```

Then you can use something like:

```
int exitValue = runProcess(your command here);
```

I guess JD-GUI will not work; you need a command line java decompiler.

These links **might** help: 
[Batch decompiling of Java files with JD-GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384619/command-line-java-decompiler-alternative-to-jd-gui)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_%28JAva_Decompiler%29

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/decompile-class-file-java-decompiler-class-java-class/

The last link has a download link to JAD, a command line tool for windows computers.

Depending on the OS the command might vary but it might just be "jad classname.class" if you move jad to your cmd class path. I have mac os x so I am not sure where this is located.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is all the decompilers I can find are GUI based.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to modify the class at runtime it may not be needed to decompile the class. You can manipulate the bytecode. Take a look at http://cglib.sourceforge.net/, maybe that'll help you

Comment: you are right..I am able to modify the bytecode. I want to then decompile the modified bytecode to do some other manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

Java IDE works fine to decompile class files. Try IntelliJ as an example, even Community Edition. It is not able to update (read only mode) but I hope it can help