# Is there a way to get the source code from an APK file?

Tags: android, android-resources, decompiling, apk

The hard drive on my laptop just crashed and I lost all the source code for an app that I have been working on for the past two months.
All I have is the APK file that is stored in my email from when I sent it to a friend.

Is there any way to extract my source code from this APK file?

Comment: FYI There is online decompiler check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21670560/1450401)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259460/decompling-an-android-apk

Comment: apk extractor app  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ext.ui&hl=en

Comment: Does this means we can get source code of million dollar worth apps like Whatsapp or Facebook?
Is this all open source?

Comment: @Faizan have you heard about proguard??

Comment: @SwiftArchitect - it is not deleted, it is still here for reference. What's your problem with closing it?

Comment: The phrasing of the question does contain irrelevant life story tidbits and as such may be interpreted as *recommend a tool*. Yet the answer could have potentially been `javac -decompile`, which would then fit SO guidelines. It appears to me that the answers are *off-topic*, not the question.

Comment: Try the online decompilers.. for more info - http://stackoverflow.com/a/27981520/3879847

Comment: in [this article](https://applidium.com/en/news/unbundling_pokemon_go/) they explain how they reverse engineer Pokemon Go

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to decompile an Android .apk file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122635/is-it-possible-to-decompile-an-android-apk-file)

Comment: keep in mind that by using online decompilers, your code may be compromised.

Comment: You can use one of [these methods](https://droidmaze.com/how-to-extract-code-from-apk/) to decompile apps and get the code.

Comment: a very general and helpful question

Comment: A simple trick: You can change your apk's extension from .apk to .zip and can view a lot of files in the apk.

Answer (score 1773, accepted):

Simplest way: use the online tool [Decompiler](https://www.decompiler.com/), upload the apk, and get the source code.

---

Procedure for decoding .apk files, step-by-step method:

#### Step 1:

1. Make a new folder and copy over the .apk file that you want to decode.
2. Now rename the extension of this .apk file to .zip (rename from filename.apk to filename.zip) and save it. Now you can access the classes.dex files. At this stage, you are able to see drawables, but not the .xml and .java files.

#### Step 2:

1. Now extract this .zip file in the same folder or a new folder.
2. [Download dex2jar](https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar) (Don't download the code, click on the releases button that's on the right, then download the file named `dex2jar-X.X.zip`) and extract it to the same folder or a new folder.
3. Move the classes.dex file into the dex2jar folder.
4. Now open Command Prompt and change the directory to that folder. Then write `d2j-dex2jar classes.dex` (for Mac or Ubuntu write `./d2j-dex2jar.sh classes.dex`) and press enter. You now have the classes.dex.dex2jar file in the same folder.
5. [Download java decompiler](http://jd.benow.ca/), Right click on jd-gui, click on Open File, and open classes.dex.dex2jar file from that folder: Now you get the class files.
6. Save all of these class files (In jd-gui, click File -> Save All Sources) by src name. At this stage, you get the Java code but the .xml files are still unreadable.

#### Step 3:

Now open another new folder

1. Put in the .apk file which you want to decode
2. Download the latest version of [apktool **AND** apktool install window](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/) (both can be downloaded from the same link) and place them in the same folder
3. Open the Command Prompt
4. Now run command `apktool if framework-res.apk` (if you don't have it [get it here](http://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23212708291677144))and next
5. `apktool d myApp.apk` (myApp.apk denotes the filename that you want to decode)

Now you get a file folder in that folder and can easily read the .xml files.

#### Step 4:

It's not any step, just copy the contents of both folders (both new folders) to a single one

AND ENJOY THE SOURCE CODE!

Comment: Thanks a lot but i have a problem after doing 3rd step all files comes n the smali format how can i read it.

Comment: @prankulgarg ,In point 5 of step 3 i am getting following error: Unable to access jarfile E:\apktojava\testt\\apktool.jar

Comment: got the problem of "jd-gui.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience." at the time saving all the java source code..

Comment: i have completed this steps but java file name is a d c b....it's posible real java file name...?

Comment: hi, i had try this Step but i m not getting  classes.dex.dex2jar file. can u help me please?

Comment: So where does one get the `framework-res.apk` file.. Am unable to find a trusted copy :|

Comment: Second file  http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui  is unavailable on this link.. what should i do?

Comment: How to do this in Ubuntu i didn't get clear idea getting problem to do this can any one help?

Comment: @prankulgarg where do we find "framework-res.apk" ? ? Google comes up with nothing ??

Comment: dex2jar is not recognized as an internal or external command. How can i solve it?

Comment: @user1451549 if you are using linux then use `./dex2jar`

Comment: I got an "Internal Error" for a main class... any suggestions?

Comment: while going through second step i got dex2jar is not recognised am using wondows.. any idea..??

Comment: Instead of  writing **dex2jar classes.dex** in cmd try out **d2j-dex2jar classes.dex**. Because dex2jar classes.dex this cmd is deprecated.

Comment: I cant extract .aidl file and interfaces included in the project? Is there any other way for that?

Comment: its just useless in my case. Also tried all suggestions in comments. Wasted my lot of time for nothing. I'm getting './dex2jar: No such file or directory' and 'd2j-dex2jar: command not found' errors.

Comment: If you are seeing class names like 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', you are trying to reverse engineer someone else's ProGuarded application.  Good luck with that.

Comment: For Step 3 of Point 5 , **error: Unable to access jarfile** I found this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15336703/1778834

Comment: I can't download framework-res.apk file at 4shared.com. It requires an annoying download manager.

Comment: Extract dex2jar-0.0.9.8.zip and copy classes.dex, which is use ./d2j-dex2jar.sh classes.dex command instead of dex2jar classes.dex , because that dex2jar classes.dex is deprecated

Comment: For those who can't find `framework-res.apk`. Download it from [here](http://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23212708291677144)

Comment: In Step 2 after src is generated when i try to compile most of java source files are showing compile time error "cannot be resolved to a type".

Comment: Step 2 command failed, From documentation (https://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/wiki/ModifyApkWithDexTool) i successfully run this : # 
d2j-dex2jar.sh -f -o test_apk-debug_dex2jar.jar test_apk-debug.apk

Comment: in my case Problem during step 4 of dex2jar : file or folder not found. Resolution:1. type bash in the command prompt 2. bash shell opens 3. go to the folder in dex2jar and run the cmd: bash d2j-dex2jar.sh classes.dex and the jar file will be generated

Comment: For those 5th step of 3rd step: [apktoolJARfile](http://connortumbleson.com/2014/11/27/apktool-rc3-released/) download here the jar file. Because command prompt says "unable to acces jar file C:\...." That jar file is on the link. Other steps is same.

Comment: can't recover XML files, getting this error when running; apktool if framework-res.apk: 
Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: java.io.FileNotFound
Exception: framework-res.apk (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.installFramework(AndrolibResource
s.java:406)
        at brut.androlib.Androlib.installFramework(Androlib.java:365)
        at brut.apktool.Main.cmdInstallFramework(Main.java:185)
        at brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:61)... [truncated]

Comment: This dex2jar link seems incomplete...It doesn't contain dex2jar.sh

Comment: @DroidWormNarendra did you found solution? I also can't found this.

Comment: @DroidWormNarendra Maybe it help you: https://dex2jar.googlecode.com/files/dex2jar-0.0.9.15.zip

Comment: I just want to add one class after that... how do I create the apk again without using Eclipse or other IDE.

Comment: For people on mac if you get permission denied when running the d2j-dex2jar.sh put sudo bash before it and inside the file on the last line add sudo bash at the front as well

Comment: **.d2j-dex2jar.sh** is not available in extract directory..! Same I tried with **dex2jar** as well, but is same, executable is not there. suggest me if anything I'm missing here

Comment: is there any way to manage the  code actually i am confused how to manage  and make a proper project, i got the  both  java  and xml files

Comment: Hi!
I might also add, that there is modern alternative to this APKTool->dex2jar->JD-GUI route!

Just try open-source APK and DEX decompiler called Jadx: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jadx/files/
It has also online version here: http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk/

Comment: make sure you give enough permissions to sh from terminal. Thus if you get an error "permission denied" while executing sh, use the following: chmod +x d2j-dex2jar.sh  chmod +x d2j_invoke.sh and then run ./d2j-dex2jar.sh classes.dex

Comment: Those who didn't find d2j-dex2jar.sh, download dex2jar from here:  https://dex2jar.googlecode.com/files/dex2jar-0.0.9.15.zip

Comment: After running ./d2j-dex2jar.sh classes.dex I got this: 
-bash: ./d2j-dex2jar.sh: Permission denied Solution is: sudo chmod +x d2j-dex2jar.sh

Comment: after all these steps you may get encoded java codes,packages etc(at complexity level pro). and your efforts will be in vein. if the apk have security like progaurd.

Comment: For people stuck in step 2:4 download this version and it will solve the problem: https://sourceforge.net/projects/dex2jar/files/dex2jar-2.0.zip/download it did for me. @delive

Comment: Here is the latest location to get d2j-d2x2jar.sh, in the dex-tools*.zip file: https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar/releases

Comment: If you get "unknown command" error in Windows , you need to run cmd.exe as Administrator

Comment: It is worth noting for future readers that the website offered in the answer produced the exact same result as the rest of the answer - so pl. don't waste time trying both. It is also worth noting that the code is full of random values like "findViewById(16908290)" and "class C07461" - and is therefore mostly unusable. Is there a way to get the original code exactly as it was coded from these random values? Thanks.

Comment: Can XML be created completely out of any apk file? Containg all the exact same functionality?

Comment: JD-GUI is a bit outdated now. Try some command line tools like CFR or Krakatau for newer versions of java.

Comment: It would be really nice, If you can teach us how to get back the key file as well, I lost one of my app key, and can not give any update to may app

Comment: Ubuntu users, move both 'apktool' and 'apktool.jar' files to '/usr/local/bin' folder. Open the terminal path pointing to the apk folder location type **apktool d <your-app-name.apk>**

Comment: I Decompiled apk using several ways but I always getting only com.android.tools folder, My source code package is missing. what is the solution for such problem?

Comment: I've tried all methods, but even with simple helloworld, although it decompile it into java, Yet, trying to open the project in android studio, and compile it back to apk, fails for many reasons (duplicatation files, etc) . Is there any method which creates java which can be compiled back to apk ?

Comment: I am getting this: `C:\Windows>apktool if framework-res.apk
S: WARNING: Could not write to (C:\Users\kbs\AppData\Local\apktool\framework), u
sing C:\Users\kbs\AppData\Local\Temp\ instead...
S: Please be aware this is a volatile directory and frameworks could go missing,
 please utilize --frame-path if the default storage directory is unavailable
I: Framework installed to: C:\Users\kbs\AppData\Local\Temp\1.apk`

Comment: I get a `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: classes.dex` but I have put `classes2.dex` in the same folder as `d2j-dex2jar` and run the CMD from that folder.

Comment: WARNING: Could not write to (C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Local\apktool\framework), using C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Local\Temp\ instead...
S: Please be aware this is a volatile directory and frameworks could go missing, please utilize --frame-path if the default storage directory is unavailable -

Comment: apktool if framework-res.apk --frame-path c:\get-xml\

Comment: Step 3 made the word "java" on files extension on the 2nd module of my app be smali. Even the java folder itself became smali. How do I fix it without renaming them one-by-one?

Comment: I have tried ```./d2j-dex2jar.sh classes.dex
```  but got ```Permission denied
``` I am using linux

Comment: Question: what if I have classes.dex, classes2.dex and classes3.dex? I decompile all three?

Comment: I am getting "The system cannot find the path specified" while running cmd - apktool if  framework-res.apk

Comment: For those getting an error of not supported version when running the dex2jar you can get this versio which works without issues: https://github.com/DexPatcher/dex2jar/releases/download/v2.1-20171001-lanchon/dex-tools-2.1-20171001-lanchon.zip

Comment: @Kousalya please write the command like this `sudo chmod +x ./d2j-dex2jar.sh classes.dex`

Comment: I got all source code but all class name is encrypted with human not understandable words like "Wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww" :)

Comment: if anyone getting "permission denied: ./d2j-dex2jar.sh" on Macbook then try "sudo chmod +x ./d2j-dex2jar.sh " in terminal then try again "./d2j-dex2jar.sh classes.dex "

Comment: I have used ./d2j-dex2jar.sh classes.dex command it is showing no such file or folder.

Comment: Be sure to also give permissions to invoke file  `sudo chmod +x d2j_invoke.sh`

Comment: This is not useful as I couldnt find the actual source code for a very simple app that I just created. How to get the actual code?

Comment: @SharadKale I got same issue too. Just use jadx from https://github.com/skylot/jadx and you'll be able to see all packages

Comment: in my case I couldn't get past Step 4 of 3 starting from the execution of "apktool if framework-res.apk" what I did was "java -jar apktool.jar apktool d MyApp.apk" and that's it

Comment: I get % sudo ./d2j-dex2jar.sh classes.dex
dex2jar classes.dex -> ./classes-dex2jar.jar
com.googlecode.d2j.DexException: not support version.
 at com.googlecode.d2j.reader.DexFileReader.<init>(DexFileReader.java:151)
 at com.googlecode.d2j.reader.DexFileReader.<init>(DexFileReader.java:211)
 at com.googlecode.dex2jar.tools.Dex2jarCmd.doCommandLine(Dex2jarCmd.java:104)
 at com.googlecode.dex2jar.tools.BaseCmd.doMain(BaseCmd.java:288)
 at com.googlecode.dex2jar.tools.Dex2jarCmd.main(Dex2jarCmd.java:32)

Comment: when i ran apktool if framework-res.apk, i got FILE NOT FOUND exception, so after downloading framework-res.apk where should i put it in?..

Comment: 'apktool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: after all the setups are sucessfull now want to recomiple as debug apk

Answer (score 144):

This is an alternative description - just in case someone got stuck with the description above. Follow the steps:

1. download [`apktool.bat`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/master/scripts/windows/apktool.bat) (or [`apktool`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/master/scripts/linux/apktool) for Linux) and [`apktool_<version>.jar`](https://bitbucket.org/iBotPeaches/apktool/downloads) from  http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/
2. rename the jar file from above to `apktool.jar` and put both files in the same folder
3. open a dos box (`cmd.exe`) and change into that folder; verify that a Java Environment is installed (for Linux check the notes regarding required libraries as well)
4. Start: `apktool decode [apk file]`

   *Intermediate result*: resource files, `AndroidManifest.xml`
5. unzip APK file with an unpacker of your choice

   *Intermediate result*: `classes.dex`
6. download and extract `dex2jar-0.0.9.15.zip` from http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/downloads/detail?name=dex2jar-0.0.9.15.zip&can=2&q=
7. drag and drop `classes.dex` onto `dex2jar.bat` (or enter `<path_to>\dex2jar.bat classes.dex` in a DOS box; for Linux use `dex2jar.sh`)

   *Intermediate result*: `classes_dex2jar.jar`
8. unpack `classes_dex2jar.jar` (might be optional depending on used decompiler)
9. decompile your class files (e.g. with [JD-GUI](http://jd.benow.ca/) or [DJ Decompiler](http://www.neshkov.com/))

   *Result*: source code

Note: it is not allowed to decompile third party packages; this guide is intended to recover personal source code from an APK file only; finally, the resulting code will most likely be obfuscated

Comment: I might also add, that there is modern alternative to this APKTool->dex2jar->JD-GUI route!

Just try open-source APK and DEX decompiler called Jadx: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jadx/files/ 
It has also online version here: http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk

Comment: It is allowed (read: legal) to decompile *any* APK file. See the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674557/is-it-legal-to-decompile-an-apk-and-use-part-of-its-code-in-your-app

Comment: Why those `apktool` return `smali` files? How to get `java` file?

Comment: @AndrewRukin That link redirect to sourceforge's dex2jar page.

Comment: I don't see the classes.dex file :(

Comment: @Ontropy unzip the APK file after renaming it and you should find the `classes.dex` file in the root folder.  If not, you might have an optimized dex file inside - see https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/720764/Some-Apk-file-doesnt-have-classes-dex.

Answer (score 131):

While you may be able to decompile your `APK` file, you will likely hit one big issue:

it's not going to return the code you wrote. It is instead going to return whatever the compiler inlined, with variables given random names, as well as functions given random names. It could take significantly more time to try to decompile and restore it into the code you had, than it will be to start over.

Sadly, things like this have killed many projects.
For the future, I highly recommend learning a Version Control System, like **CVS**, **SVN** and **git** etc.

and how to back it up.

Answer (score 58):

There is also a new application on the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.njlabs.showjava) with which it is possible to decompile an APK (system applications too) and view the source code right on your smartphone. It saves the files to your SD card so you can view them on your computer too. It does not require root or something else.

Just install it and have fun. I think this is the easiest way to decompile an app.

Comment: @MidhunVijayakumar could you able to to the apk to source code conversion using this?

Answer (score 30):

[apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) is the best thing you can try. I have saved some xml with it, but honestly I don't know how it will work with the .java code.

I would recommend you to have a code repository even if your are the only coder. I've been using [Project Locker](http://www.projectlocker.com/) for my own projects. It gives you free svn and git repos.

Comment: You will find apktool indispensible if you want to extract resources (i.e. images from an Android application. Actually, the tool has no competitors at all!) An online version of the apktool is available here: www.javadecompilers.com/apktool

Answer (score 26):

These two articles describe how to combine the use of `apktool` and `dex2jar` to take an `APK` file and create an Eclipse project that can build and run it.

> http://blog.inyourbits.com/2012/11/extending-existing-android-applications.html
>
> http://blog.inyourbits.com/2012/12/extending-existing-android-applications.html

Basically you:

1. Use `apktool` to get the resource files out of the apk
2. Use `dex2jar` to get a jar file that contains the classes in a format that Eclipse will like.
3. Create an Eclipse project point it at the resource files and the new jar file
4. Open the jar file with a zip utility and delete the existing resources
5. Open the jar file with `JDGui` to view the source code
6. Take whatever source code you need from `JDGui`, stick it in a class inside Eclipse and modify it
7. Delete that class from the jar file (so you don't have the same class defined multiple times)
8. Run it.

Comment: I know this question is answered still , i would like to pass a information :

there is a online decompiler for android apks

http://www.decompileandroid.com/

Upload apk from local machine, 
Wait some moments, 
download source code in zip format.

Comment: Sounds nice.  And then the decompileandroid website also has a copy of all of your source!  Clever!

Comment: One question, I have an apk decompiled but in jd gui I dont know if there are the real classes of java, do you know if an apk is decompiled are there the real Java classes ?

Answer (score 23):

apktool will work. You don't even need to know the keystore to extract the source code (which is a bit scary). The main downside is that the source is presented in Smali format instead of Java. Other files such as the icon and main.xml come through perfectly fine though and it may be worth your time to at least recover those. Ultimately, you will most likely need to re-write your Java code from scratch.

You can find apktool [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/). Simply just download apktool and the appropriate helper (for Windows, Linux, or Mac OS). I recommend using a tool such as 7-zip to unpack them.

Answer (score 21):

There are a few ways to do this:

1. Use the "Profile or Debug APK" feature in Android Studio 3.0.

It allows you to open and explore APKs in Android Studio. Classes are decompiled into smali. Resources are not extracted and things like "Go to Definition", "Find All References" and debugging don't work without the source code (android studio 3.0 canary 9). Some additional smali features might work with [smalidea](https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali/wiki/smalidea).

2. Use [jadx](https://github.com/skylot/jadx).

Jadx decompiles the code in a given APK to java source files.

3. Use [apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/).

Apktool is a command line tool which extracts resources and decompiles code into smali for a given apk. You can recompile using apktool also. Here's an example of it in action:

```
    $ apktool d test.apk
    I: Using Apktool 2.2.4 on test.apk
    I: Loading resource table...
    I: Decoding AndroidManifest.xml with resources...
    I: Loading resource table from file: 1.apk
    I: Regular manifest package...
    I: Decoding file-resources...
    I: Decoding values */* XMLs...
    I: Baksmaling classes.dex...
    I: Copying assets and libs...
    I: Copying unknown files...
    I: Copying original files...
    $ apktool b test
    I: Using Apktool 2.2.4 on test
    I: Checking whether sources has changed...
    I: Smaling smali folder into classes.dex...
    I: Checking whether resources has changed...
    I: Building resources...
    I: Building apk file...
    I: Copying unknown files/dir...
```

Comment: I've tried jadx, but even with simple helloworld, although it decompile it into java, Yet, trying to open the project in android studio, and compile it back to apk, fails for many reasons (duplicatation files, etc) . Is there any method which creates java which can be compiled back to apk ?

Comment: @ransh I typically use jadx to read the code then apktool to modify the code. apktool doesn't create java but it allows for re-compiling.

Comment: 0xcaff, thanks for clarification. that make sense now. Becuase trying to compile a decompile java in android studio, was not working.

Answer (score 20):

May be the easy one to see the source:

In Android studio 2.3, `Build -> Analyze APK -> Select the apk that you want to decompile`.
You will see it's source code.

Link for reference:
https://medium.com/google-developers/making-the-most-of-the-apk-analyzer-c066cb871ea2

Comment: It lists classes and methods but does not give source code.

Comment: You can get the above files only by changing ".apk" to ".zip"

Answer (score 9):

Below **ONLINE** tool:

http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk

it do ALL by one click: decompiled **.java files + resources + xml** (in one .zip file) with very good decompiler (jadx return java code in places/functions  where other compiles return comments inside function like "unable to decompile" or some android assembler/machine code)

Comment: yes, this is great, but instead of function names, it has changed all the functions names to CS1001 and so on. So how to recognize these.
and one thing more that, Can we use this decompiled apk directly as our Android studio project, Will it work?

Comment: then for what purpose we use to decompile some ones apk, if we can't use their functionality in our apps.

Comment: @ZiaUrRahman I don't know. However I in my case I decompile code to analyse algorithm. Do you check does decompiled code from that tool can be compiled by android studio in fully automatic way - or need some "human processing"?

Comment: I imported the decompiled project in android studio, but No gradle there and the project have many files but didn't understand until we run it. Simply it didn't work. I need to make the decompiled project fully funtional in android studio and then get some core functionality of some ones, then want to use/embed it in my own project. So is there any way that how to do this?

Comment: This online tool is using Jadx that anyone can download and run in their own computer with benefit of not having ads keep blinking in your face every 5 seconds. Also it fails the same way Jadx fails

Answer (score 8):

This site https://www.apkdecompilers.com/ did it automatically.

I tried the site mentioned in the accepted answer first but that didn't work for me.

Comment: i couldnt retrive my java source code ... it appeare somethins like  attached file and ..

Comment: @imankazemayni in the link above, "browse" to your APK file and click on "Decompile your APK". It'll take some time and then it should give you the source code, if the code is not Encrypted.

Comment: do you know is multidex  impact on encrypting?

Answer (score 8):

based on your condition, if your android apk:

## Condition1: NOT harden (by Tencent Legu/Qihoo 360/...)

### Choice1: using online service

such as:

#### using [www.javadecompilers.com](http://www.javadecompilers.com)

goto:

- http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk

  - Note: internally using [Jadx](https://github.com/skylot/jadx)

to auto decode from apk to java sourcecode

steps:

`upload` apk file + click `Run` + wait some time + click `Download` to get zip + unzip ->

`sources/com/{yourCompanyName}/{yourProjectName}`

is your expected java source code

### Choice2: decompile/crack by yourself

use related tool to decompile/crack by yourself:

#### use `jadx`/`jadx-gui` convert `apk` to `java sourcecode`

download [jadx-0.9.0.zip](https://github.com/skylot/jadx/releases/download/v0.9.0/jadx-0.9.0.zip) then unzip to got `bin/jadx`, then:

- command line mode:

  - in terminal run: `jadx-0.9.0/bin/jadx -o output_folder /path_to_your_apk/your_apk_file.apk`

    - output_folder will show decoded `sources` and `resources`

      - `sources/com/{yourCompanyName}/{yourProjectName}` is your expected `java sourcecode`
- GUI mode

  - double click to run `jadx-0.9.0/bin/jadx-gui` (Linux's `jadx-gui.sh` / Windows's `jadx-gui.bat`)

    - open `apk` file
    - it will auto decoding -> see your expected java sourcecode
    - `save all` or `save as Gradle project`

## Condition2: harden (by Tencent Legu/Qihoo 360/...)

the main method of `3 steps`:

1. `apk/app to dex`
2. `dex to jar`
3. `jar to java src`

detailed explanation:

### Step1: `apk/app to dex`

use tool (`FDex2`/DumpDex) dump/hook out (one or multiple) `dex` file from running app

steps:

#### prepare environment

- a `root`ed android

  - real phone
  - or emulator

    - here using **Chinese** [Nox App Player夜神安卓模拟器](https://www.yeshen.com)
- install your android apk

  - to the phone or emulator
- installed [Xposed Installer](https://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer)
- install `FDex2`/[DumpDex](https://github.com/WrBug/dumpDex) into XPosed and enable it

  - Note: need **restart** Xposed to make FDex2 work
  - FDex2 download address, **Chinese**:

    - [脱壳工具 FDex2-CSDN下载](https://download.csdn.net/download/crifan/11057898)
    - 链接: https://pan.baidu.com/s/1lTF8CN96bxWpFwv7J174lg 提取码: 3e3t
- install your android apk to phone/emulator

#### dump out `dex` from running app

- run `FDex2` then click your apk name to enable later to capture/hook out dex
- (in phone/emulator) run your app
- find and copy out the dump out whole apk resources in `/data/data/com/yourCompanyName/yourProjectName`

  - in its root folder **normally** will find several `dex` file

### Step2:  `dex to jar`

use tool (`dex2jar`) convert (the specific, containing app logic) `dex` file to `jar` file

download [dex2jar](https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar) got [dex-tools-2.1-SNAPSHOT.zip](https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar/files/1867564/dex-tools-2.1-SNAPSHOT.zip), unzip got `dex-tools-2.1-SNAPSHOT/d2j-dex2jar.sh`, then

`sh dex-tools-2.1-SNAPSHOT/d2j-dex2jar.sh -f your_dex_name.dex`

eg:

```
dex-tools-2.1-SNAPSHOT/d2j-dex2jar.sh -f com.xxx.yyy8825612.dex
dex2jar com.xxx.yyy8825612.dex -> ./com.xxx.yyy8825612-dex2jar.jar
```

### Step3: `jar to java src`

use one of tools:

- [Jadx](https://github.com/skylot/jadx)
- [Procyon](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon)

  - GUI tool based on procyon:

    - [Luyten](https://github.com/deathmarine/Luyten)
    - [Bytecode Viewer](https://github.com/Konloch/bytecode-viewer)
- [CRF](https://www.benf.org/other/cfr/)
- [JD-GUI](http://java-decompiler.github.io)
- some others:

  - [Krakatau](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau)
  - [Fernflower](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins/java-decompiler/engine)
  - [Cavaj](https://cavaj-java-decompiler.jaleco.com/)

convert `jar` to `java src`

for from jar to java src converting effect:

`Jadx` > `Procyon` > `CRF` >> `JD-GUI`

so recommend use: `Jadx`/`jadx-gui`

steps:

- double click to run `jadx-gui`
- open `dex` file
- `File` -> `save all`

---

More detailed explanation can see my online ebook **Chinese** tutorial:

- [安卓应用的安全和破解](https://book.crifan.com/books/android_app_security_crack/website/)

  - tutorial's source code on github: [crifan/android_app_security_crack: 安卓应用的安全和破解](https://github.com/crifan/android_app_security_crack)

Answer (score 6):

**apktool** is THE way to go.
Online apktool service exists as well: http://www.javadecompilers.com/apktool

Some limitations, obviously, exist due to the service ‘online nature’: you may extract and research assets and the manifest file, but it is impossible to recompile the application at the moment.

Still, this is a no-hassle way to 'open' the android application.

Answer (score 5):

I'll show you other way to decompile the **.apk** files.

You can follow the first 2 steps from "**prankul garg**". So you have another opportunities:

**Step 3':**

Download the **"JD-GUI"**, thats easy to found this one.
Open your **.jar** file in "jd-gui.exe". (File > Open file > 'found your **.jar** file'). After this procedure, you can save all resources in a **.zip** file.

So,

1st - You have to rename the **.apk** file to **.zip**

2nd - You have to decode **.dex** file (if you want, decode the **.apk** file to **dex2jar**, that's possible)

3rd - You have to decode **.jar** file with **JD-GUI**

Comment: What does this answer provide that the others don't?

Comment: You don't really have to rename it to zip. I could open the apk file directly with 7-zip.

Answer (score 5):

**Apktool** for reverse engineering 3rd party, closed, binary Android apps.

It can decode resources to nearly original form and rebuild them after making some modifications.

It makes possible to debug smali code step by step. Also it makes working with an app easier because of project-like file structure and automation of some repetitive tasks like building apk, etc.

http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/

Answer (score 4):

You can try [DexPatcher](https://github.com/DexPatcher/dexpatcher-tool). It even integrates with Android Studio. It uses [Apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) and [Dex2Jar](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dex2jar/) internally.
You can use those tools independently as well.
[Apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) decompiles apk, and extracts .dex files, which can further be converted to jar using Dex2Jar. Jar can be decompiled by using [JD-GUI](http://jd.benow.ca/). You can see the Java code with the help of that tool. Although the similarity of decompiled code to the actual code cannot be guaranteed. There are some advanced [code obfuscation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)) tools available in the market, which mess up the code to make it difficult to decompile /  understand. eg. Proguard

Comment: Hello How to use DexPatcher with Android Studio?

Comment: Can't explain everything in comments.
Google is your friend :) There are some nice youtube tutorials as well.

Answer (score 4):

**Single click solution** (Windows only)

after reading this loooooonnnnnngggg post,
i have decided to create an automated process to decompile APKs in a single click,

i have decided to share it on github:
https://github.com/shaybc/apk-decompiler

```
simply unzip,
copy the apk you want to decompile into "apk-source" folder
and run "go.bat"
find the result in the: "apk-output" folder
```

thats it, enjoy

Answer (score 3):

Android studio offers you to analyse any apk file.

1 - From build menu choose analyse apk option and select apk file.
2 - This will result in you the classes.dex file and other files.
3 - Click on classes.dex which will give you the list of folders, packages, libraries and files.
4 - From and android studio settings install a plugin called "Dex to Jar" 
5 - click on any activity file of your extracted project and choose dex to jar from the build menu.

This will result in you the actual code of your java file.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Step 1:
Make a new folder and copy over the .apk file that you want to decode.

Now rename the extension of this .apk file to .zip (e.g. rename from filename.apk to filename.zip) and save it. Now you can access the classes.dex files, etc. At this stage you are able to see drawables but not xml and java files, so continue.

Step 2:
Now extract this .zip file in the same folder (or NEW FOLDER).

Download https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar/releases/tag/2.0 : dex2jar-2.0

Now open command prompt and change directory to that folder (or NEW FOLDER). Then execute :
`d2j-dex2jar.bat classes.dex`

Download this decompiler http://java-decompiler.github.io/ to decompile classes-dex2jar.jar

Step 3:
Now open another new folder

Put in the .apk file which you want to decode

Download the latest version of apktool AND apktool (https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/) install window (both can be downloaded from the same link) and place them in the same folder

Open a command window

Now run command like apktool if framework-res.apk (if you don't have it get it here)and next

apktool d myApp.apk (where myApp.apk denotes the filename that you want to decode)

now you get a file folder in that folder and can easily read the apk's xml files.

Copycontents of both folders to a single folder

Done !

Answer (score 1):

I found the following as the simplest method:

1. Rename your app.apk to app.zip (Change extension from apk to zip)
2. Extract the zip file into a folder
3. Use [JADX](https://github.com/skylot/jadx) tool to read the source code, present in classes.dex file.

Answer (score 1):

There's an app for that and generally takes just a few clicks and you are done.
https://github.com/Nuvolect/DeepDive-Android

1. Select Apps, under "Installed Apps" select your app. If it is not
   there you can load the APK.
2. Select "Extract APK"
3. Select "Unpack APK"
4. Select "Decompile with Jadx". This can take a few seconds or a few minutes depending 
   on the speed of your device

After that you can browse the source code, download it to another computer with elFinder or search through it using Lucene.

In addition to Jadx it has CFR and Fernflower decompilers.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Extracting the source from a native Android application**

The source code of a native Android application is not difficult to obtain, but it does require extra tools that are compatible with Windows, Mac, and Linux. My personal favorites when it comes to tools are [dex2jar](https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar) and [JD-GUI](http://java-decompiler.github.io/).

If you’re unfamiliar with these tools, dex2jar will read Dalvik Executable files and convert them to the standard JAR format. JD-GUI will read JAR files and decompile the class files found in them.

To make the extraction process easier to understand, let’s start by creating a fresh native Android project:

```
android create project --target 19 --name TestProject --path . --activity TestProjectActivity --package com.nraboy.testproject
```

The above command will leave you with an Android project in your current command prompt path.

Since our project has an Activity class already included, lets jump straight into the build process. You can give me a hard time all day long about using Ant instead of Gradle or Maven, but for this tutorial I’m going to stick with it.

```
ant debug
```

The above command will create a debug build typically found at **bin/TestProject-debug.apk**.

Using your favorite unzip tool, extract the APK file. 7-zip is a popular tool, but if you’re on a Mac you can just run the following from the Terminal:

```
unzip TestProject-debug.apk
```

This will leave us with a bunch of files and folders, but one is important to us. Make note of classes.dex because it contains all of our source code. To convert it into something readable we need to run dex2jar on it. You can use dex2jar on Mac, Linux, and Windows, but I’m going to explain from a Mac perspective.

With the **classes.dex** file in your extracted **dex2jar** directory, run the following from the Terminal:

```
./dex2jar.sh classes.dex
```

Open the JD-GUI application that you downloaded because it is now time to decode the JAR and packaged class files. Open the freshly created **classes_dex2jar.jar** file and you should see something like the following:

[image]
See how easy it was to get to the source code of your native Android APK? Now what can you do to better protect yourself?

The Android SDK ships with [Proguard](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code), which is a obfuscation module. What is obfuscation you ask?

Obfuscation via [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation):

> Obfuscation (or beclouding) is the hiding of intended meaning in
> communication, making communication confusing, willfully ambiguous,
> and harder to interpret.

While obfuscation will not encrypt your source code, it will make it more difficult to make sense of. With Proguard configured, run Ant in release mode and your code should be obfuscated on build.

**2. Extracting the source from a hybrid Android application**

The source code of hybrid applications are by far the easiest to extract. You don’t need any extra software installed on your computer, just access to the APK file.

To make things easier to understand, lets first create a fresh Apache Cordova project and then extract it. Start by doing the following:

```
cordova create TestProject com.example.testproject TestProject
cd TestProject
cordova platform add android
```

During the project creation process you are left with the default Apache Cordova CSS, HTML, and JavaScript templates. That is fine for us in this example. Let’s go ahead and build our project into a distributed APK file:

```
cordova build android
```

You’re going to be left with **platforms/android/ant-build/CordovaApp-debug.apk or something along the lines of platforms/android/ant-build/*-debug.apk**.

Even though this is a debug build, it is still very usable. With [7-zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) or similar installed, right click the APK file and choose to extract or unzip it. In the extracted directory, you should now have access to all your web based source files. I say web based because any Java files used by Apache Cordova will have been compiled into class files. However, CSS, HTML, and JavaScript files do not get touched.

You just saw how depressingly easy it is to get hybrid application source code. So what can you do to better protect yourself?

You can uglify your code, which is a form of obfuscation.

Doing this will not encrypt your code, but it will make it that much more difficult to make sense of.

If you want to uglify your code, I recommend you install [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) since it is pretty much the standard as of now. If you prefer to use a task runner, Grunt and Gulp have modules for UglifyJS as well.

Answer (score 1):

**There are lots of applications and methods in the market to decompile the apk file into java class but if the app is compiled with ProGuard rule then you are in a big trouble because this rule will shrink all the dex files into a small character name and then you can not trace back the implementation.** see https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code for mode clarification.

Happy Coding...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is using Apk OneClick Decompiler. That is a tool package to decompile & disassemble APKs (android packages).

**FEATURES**

- All features are integrated into the right-click menu of Windows.
- Decompile APK classes to Java source codes.
- Disassemble APK to smali code and decode its resources.
- Install APK to phone by right-click.
- Recompile APK after editing smali code and/or resources.
  During recompile:
- Optimize png images
- Sign apks
- Zipalign

**REQUIREMENTS**

Java Runtime Environment (JRE) must be installed.

You can download it from this link [Apk OneClick Decompiler](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=873466)

Answer (score 0):

I've been driving myself crazy for days trying to get dex2jar to work on a fedora 31 laptop against an apk that just wasn't going to work.  This python 3 script did the trick in minutes and installing jd-gui made class files human readable.

http://java-decompiler.github.io/

https://github.com/Storyyeller/enjarify

specifically, here's what I ran:

```
# i installed apktool before the rest of the stuff, may not need it but here it is
$> cd /opt
$> sudo mkdir apktool
$> cd apktool/
$> sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/master/scripts/linux/apktool
$> sudo wget https://bitbucket.org/iBotPeaches/apktool/downloads/apktool_2.4.1.jar
$> sudo mv apktool_2.4.1.jar apktool.jar
$> sudo mv apktool* /usr/bin/
$> sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/apktool*

# and enjarify
$> cd /opt
$> sudo git clone https://github.com/Storyyeller/enjarify.git
$> cd enjarify/
$> sudo ln -s /opt/enjarify/enjarify.sh /usr/bin/enjarify

# and finally jd-gui
$> cd /opt
$> sudo git clone https://github.com/java-decompiler/jd-gui.git
$> cd jd-gui/
$> sudo ./gradlew build

# I made an alias to kick of the jd-gui with short commandline rather than long java -jar blahblahblah :)
$> echo "jd-gui='java -jar /opt/jd-gui/build/launch4j/lib/jd-gui-1.6.6.jar'" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Now one should be able to rum the following to get class files:

```
$> enjarify yourapkfile.apk
```

And to start jd-gui:

```
$> jd-gui
```

Then just open your class files!

Answer (score 0):

I developed a Tool - Code Analyzer, it runs in iPhone/iPad/Mac, to analyze Java/Android files, https://decompile.io

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### For Java files

Use the accepted answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6081365/17133283)

#### For XML files

You need not use the method given in the accepted answer as I felt it complicated.

What I did instead was to convert the APK file to ZIP and extract it. After extracting, I got a folder named res:

[image]

I just opened it and found many folders. For the layout, you need to find the folder named `layout` not any other one like layout-land or something. The same thing can be done with the other resources like drawable, menu etc...

**NOTE:** There will be a lot of random files also which are NOT created by you. You can find the files made by you and then use them!

Answer (score -1):

Use this tool
http://www.javadecompilers.com/

But recently, a new wave of decompilers has forayed onto the market:  **Procyon,  CFR,  JD,  Fernflower,  Krakatau,  Candle.**

Here's a list of decompilers presented on this site:

*CFR* - 
Free, no source-code available, http://www.benf.org/other/cfr/
Author: Lee Benfield

Very well-updated decompiler! CFR is able to decompile modern Java features - Java 9 modules, Java 8 lambdas, Java 7 String switches etc.
It'll even make a decent go of turning class files from other JVM langauges back into java!

*JD* - 
free for non-commercial use only, http://jd.benow.ca/
Author: Emmanuel Dupuy

Updated in 2015. Has its own visual interface and plugins to Eclipse and IntelliJ . Written in C++, so very fast. Supports Java 5.

*Procyon* - 
open-source, https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/wiki/Java%20Decompiler
Author: Mike Strobel

*Fernflower* - 
open-source, https://github.com/fesh0r/fernflower
Author: Egor Ushakov

Updated in 2015. Very promising analytical Java decompiler, now becomes an integral part of IntelliJ 14. (https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins/java-decompiler)
Supports Java up to version 6 (Annotations, generics, enums)

*JAD* - 
given here only for historical reason. Free, no source-code available, jad download mirror
Author: Pavel Kouznetsov

Answer (score -1):

APK files of Android apps can be decompiled using any of the following methods:

1. APKTool (need Java to be installed on your PC)
2. APKTool M (Android application)
3. JavaDecompilers (Online Tool include APKTool utility)

Source: https://droidmaze.com/how-to-extract-code-from-apk/