# Protect information in Android

Tags: java, android, security

### Problem Description

I am writing application for Android. Application must do following:

1. Connect to the server using following URL:

   > http://www.example.com/database.xml?username=xxx&password=xxx

   username and password I must keep in the phone and this username and password are same for the all users. For example if 1.000.000 people have my application they all connect to the server using same url same username and password.
2. Download database.xml file from URL and save data in the SQLite database.

---

### Issues

1. How I can use URL in my application to be sure that users which have access to my codes can't know from the code which URL I use and also to keep secure my password and username.
   Or even just to keep whole URL secure http://www.example.com/database.xml?username=xxx&password=xxx as it is same for all users.
2. How I can protect my SQLite database. For example if somebody has root access on the phone he can get database open it and get all information which I keep there.

I need to protect my data.

Comment: "I need just protect my information from the most of users" -- then you do not need to do anything. However, "I need just protect my information from the most of users" does not line up with "if somebody has root access on the phone", as "most of users" do not have root access. You need to make up your mind whether you are trying to protect against "most of users" or not.

Comment: @CommonsWare can I protect my data from everybody? and if I can, how I can do that ?

Comment: "can I protect my data from everybody?" -- no.

Comment: @CommonsWare I guess that :) And how I can try to protect from the 97% of the people who use my app?

Comment: "And how I can try to protect from the 97% of the people who use my app?" -- do nothing. 97% of your users have no access to the APK contents or internal storage. The 3% who do can do what they want, because it is **their data**, not yours. Once it is on their device, it is their data, not yours. If you do not want it to be their data, then do not put it on their device. For example, use a different URL that does not embed a username and password in it.

Comment: @CommonsWare And if I crypt data before adding it or I get crypt data from the server and than decrypt it in the place where I must use it in app. I guess I can't keep it in that case too. As 3% can access to my codes and get algorithms of decription and encryption. Am I right?

Comment: "As 3% can access to my codes and get algorithms of decription and encryption. Am I right?" -- anyone who can get at the data can get at the APK and can arrange to have it reverse-engineered to get at your algorithms and keys.

Comment: SqlCipher can do database encryption and to secure your url you can also use "POST" methods and encrypted data.

Comment: @CommonsWare So there is no way to keep any data secure if it is in someones pocket not yours. And what about Chintan Rathod suggestion?

Comment: "And what about Chintan Rathod suggestion?" -- anyone who can root their device can get at the encryption key used with SQLCipher.

Comment: @CommonsWare, what will you say about ProGaurd?

Comment: @ChintanRathod: For something as simple as finding an DRM encryption key (and what VITO Brothers wants to do boils down to DRM), ProGuard will not be a major impediment.

Comment: Also note that if you're using HTTP, rather than HTTPS, someone can get at your data even without a rooted device. They can just sniff the packets or use a proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should go for [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html). I know its very hard to prevent from reverse-engineering. Following are some post which give some knowledge about this.

- [How to avoid reverse engineering of an APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854425/how-to-avoid-reverse-engineering-of-an-apk-file)
- [Is it really impossible to protect Android apps from reverse engineering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336637/is-it-really-impossible-to-protect-android-apps-from-reverse-engineering)

[Protecting Your Android Applications](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1725260) is an article which describes necessary information about ProGuard.

Read [FAQ](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#FAQ.html) to know more.

To protect database, use [SQLCipher](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android/).

Comment: get link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184492/best-way-to-secure-android-app-sensitive-data.. must read.

Answer (score 0):

1. use [HttpRequest](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpRequest.html) apis to get the data instead of using browser intent.
2. In your case I don't see any perfect protection engineering. Any one with a primary reverse engineering knowledge can get the data from your code.

Comment: 1.I don't use browser intent. I use HTTPClient and HTTPGet. So but data on the server is protected with password.
2. And how data protection can be done, if not in my case ?