# Why is it not possible to get a code from apk..?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to decompile an Android .apk file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122635/is-it-possible-to-decompile-an-android-apk-file)

Hi,
  i came to know that its not possible to get our source code for an apk. i wanted to know why it cannot be decompiled.? Anyone please clear my doubt. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The android apk is the type of dex convert the dex to jar and then the jar will be easily converted back to .java. Then you have then complete source code. Tested

Answer (score 0):

it's possible but not fully.. u can see all code from apk ... for new complie u need override some classes. Here solution for you question : [how to decomplie apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168362/decompiler-for-apk)
two weeks ago ... i do it.. but way to do it is hard :( .