# Downgrade app in Google Play ? (android market)

Tags: android, apk, google-play

I uploaded a app for the market, and then uploaded a 2.0 version... but then we decided that the first one was better, but i cant reactivate the 1.0 because it says **"Error: APK version 1 supports all the same devices as other APKs with higher versions. It would not be served. Please deactivate an APK."**
any how to activate the 1.0 that is already uploaded?
Or any how to open the apk (1.0) in eclipse, save and upload it as 3.0?
(I have only the apk 1.0 because i did the 2.0 in the same project)
thanks

Comment: You need to start using version control. That way you can get the source code for any version you've tagged.

Comment: On a sidenote you should start using git: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29. You can host private git projects at https://bitbucket.org/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, the APK version of your 2.0 is higher than the APK version of 1.0 and a new APK should have a higher APK version.

You could access the source code of 1.0 by [decompiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122635/is-it-possible-to-decompile-an-android-apk-file).

Comment: Just to be clarify a little - the parameter in charge is versionCode, and not versionName.

Answer (score 0):

Deactivate version 2.0, Activate Version 1.0.

I don't know if that will *downgrade* anyone who has already upgraded to 2.0, but it will stop anyone who hasn't upgraded from downloading 2.0.

If you want to be sure that everyone goes back to the code from version 1.0, you may need to re-distribute 1.0 as 3.0 which will guarantee people on 2.0 can "upgrade" to the old code base.

**Edit**: I read the question poorly. I didn't realize you don't have the source code for version 1.0 anymore. In that case, you can't really re-distribute 1.0 as 3.0

Also, you need to go into "advanced" mode in google play in order to see all previously uploaded APK's which will let you activate/deactivate whichever ones you want.