# Decompiling Android apk

Tags: android, reverse-engineering

I have already compiled android application(.apk file).
I want to change it, to show splash screen before starting.
Can I do this without any source code?

Comment: Please follow this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/android-getting-source-code-from-an-apk-file

Comment: Decompiling an apk is way more time consuming than just creating another apk after modifying the source.

Comment: @user1092042 such claims are usually just excuses not to say "I'm stealing this app from my competitor"

Comment: "or the my client is doing it" ))

Comment: First of all; do you have permission to modify the application from its creator? If so, you are probably best of asking for the source directly.

Answer (score 4):

Not really.

Decompiling is *not* a direct process.  You lose a large amount of information in the compilation process (variable names get thrown away, comments get thrown out, etc...).  For Android:

- An APK is simply a zip file with a set of classes and resources.
- Those classes are compiled into a `.dex` file.
- That `.dex` file contains code which is somewhat like Java virtual machine code.
- You can translate dex to jars using the tool `dex2jar`.
- After doing this, you can simply using a Java decompiler.

However, as your original question asks, modifying the code this way is basically impossible, produces an unmaintainable pile of horrible code.  It will take you a long time to do this as well, partly understanding how the decompiled code works (as there won't be any comments or intermediate variable names), and then modify that...

Answer (score 0):

See [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122635/is-it-possible-to-decompile-an-android-apk-file)

> First, an apk file is just a modified jar file. So the real question is can they decompile the dex files inside. The answer is sort of.

So it would be easiest if you just modded the source code you used to compile your .APK