# How to prevent reverse engineering of an Android APK file to secure code?

Tags: android, apk

I have an app source and its [APK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29) file. Now I want to prevent this APK file from being reverse engineered. If it is possible to secure my app from reverse engineering, what are the steps to follow in my coding or any library is used for that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to decompile an Android .apk file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122635/is-it-possible-to-decompile-an-android-apk-file)

Comment: Went to a good talk on this at Devoxx UK - check it out [here](http://www.parleys.com/play/5167dc5ce4b05b6ad71fa6fb/chapter0/about)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid reverse engineering of an APK file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854425/how-to-avoid-reverse-engineering-of-an-apk-file)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Now I want to prevent this APK file from being reverse engineered.

That is impossible, sorry.

> If it is possible to secure my app from reverse engineering, what are the steps to follow in my coding or any library is used for that?

ProGuard, properly configured, will obfuscate your code. DexGuard, a commercial extended version of ProGuard, may help a bit more. However, your code can still be converted into `smali`, and developers with reverse-engineering experience will be able to learn what you do from that `smali` code.

If you do not want others seeing your code, do not store that code on their device.

Comment: How not to store the code on their device? Let's say they have a rooted device and downloaded your APK for the first time. They got your APK and can start from there right?

Comment: @Halim: "How not to store the code on their device?" -- put your business logic on your server, and have your app talk to your server.