# How to open a java file in android?

Tags: java, android, xml

Hi I am new to Android and **I have an apk file from which I extracted the source code**.

My problem is that now I need to ***open all the java and xml files in eclipse*** as a new Android project for editing.

Right now I am only able to view the java class but not able to run it i.e; I cannot put it in a project I have created. When I try to read the xml files it shows some garbage values.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: for getting xml files properly you have to unsign apk first and then extract xml files

Comment: I have already did all those. How do i open it in eclipse.

Comment: just copy the contents and paste it in your own java file; make sure the class file names are same to avoid confusion

Comment: i have around 30 class files isnt there a method to import  it directly into my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly refer this blog post, [GT's Blog](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.in/2011/12/android-reverse-engineering-decompile.html) also this StackOverflow Question [decompiling DEX into Java sourcecode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122635/is-it-possible-to-decompile-an-android-apk-file)

You can try to decompile some of the .class files but I never tried to do it for the XML files. I found a discussion in XDA Developers Blog which may help you. [How to decompile/recompile binary XML from .apk file?](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=519397)

Answer (score 2):

An .apk files is package that contains the compiled code, not source code.  No java files live in there, just the android .class equivalent -- the classes.dex file.  There is no way to get the original source (.java files) from the .apk.

Comment: so what yo mean is that i need to open that class and copy the code and paste it into my project?

Comment: if you have .java files you can import them into eclipse. If you already have a project in eclipse, use `File->Import...` then `General->Filesystem` and browse to the directory they are in.