# i need to understand phonegap mysql remote security

Tags: mysql, security, cordova

am running a phonegap app android where user can insert record into database via a form input.
question is during compilation and deployment of the app

1.will my database username,password,tables etc from php servers folder be compiled with the app.
2. can my phonegap app be decompile by hackers to get my database accounts from php server

1. if yes, how do i 100% protect my database account from being hacked via phonegap app downloaded by my users.
2. finally how do i also 99.9% protect my css,html,js files in www folder of the phonegap app

thanks

Comment: Why you u not use API - Webservice methods for get n post details ?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you escape the user input values properly, there will not be any chance to get the database or table details. Please check [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)
2. Check [Is it possible to decompile an Android .apk file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122635/is-it-possible-to-decompile-an-android-apk-file)

Comment: Sir am using PDO and there is no possibility of sql injection attack. for html output am using function htmlspecialchars or htmlentities. for csrf am using nounce. am not talking about attack. my quesion is will my database username,password,tables etc from php servers folder be compiled and displayed inside the phonegap app my users download