# How easy is it to transform a signed APK back to the source code?

Tags: java, android, apk, signed

I priced a project in two phases:

- App
- Source Code

Is it possible to give my client (tech-oriented) a signed APK without giving him access to the source code (as the source code is priced separately)? Would he be able to transform the signed APK (classes.dex) back to readable classes? If so how can I upload an APK to a client's Play store account without giving him access to the source?

Answer (score 1):

The code can always be de-compiled even from a signed APK, but it's your job to make it obscure so that people find it difficult to understand the functionality. You can use ProGuard in Android to [obfuscate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)) your code.

Read [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122635/is-it-possible-to-decompile-an-android-apk-file).

Read [this article](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html) to know how to use ProGuard.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) (free) or [DexGuard](https://www.guardsquare.com/dexguard) (commercial) to obfuscate your files. Signing prevents addition to your packages but does not prevent decompilation.