# How to distribute an Android application (so that people cannot see the source)

Tags: android, executable

I have some java code that I want to share with some classmates however I do not want to share the source with them.

What is the standard method to provide someone with a Java executable that they can use but they cannot see the source.

Not sure if this is relevant but the code that I will be giving them will be run on android.

Comment: Note that your classmates may be clever enough to know how to run a Java decompiler.

Comment: @Greg that won't do them any good, Android doesn't compile to a JVM byte code, it compiles to a special byte code that only can be decompiled to assembly like instructions right now. They won't be able to get "Java source" from a .dex file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "they can use".

If you just want them to be able to run your application on their phones (or emulators) you can give them [an `.apk` file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_(file_format)), which is the standard format for Android Applications.  The easiest way to produce an `.apk` is to use the Android Development Tools (ADT) plugin for Eclipse.  Otherwise you'll have to use the [`aapt` command](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aapt.html).

If you want to allow them to add your classes to their applications you'll have to give them a `.jar` file containing your compiled `.class` files.  However, it is possible to turn `.class` files back into `.java` files using a decompiler so you if you really don't want them to see your code you may be stuck.

There are tools - known as obfuscators - which make the decompiling process harder, but personally I wouldn't bother with them here as they also make debugging harder too.

It won't be possible for anyone to turn your `.apk` back into source.  Android uses a different Virtual Machine to standard Java and so has `.dex` files with Dalvik bytecode rather than `.class` files with JVM bytecode, and currently there are no tools that turn `.dex` files back in to `.java` source files.

Answer (score 1):

Package only the class files into a .jar file and don't give them the source.

**Edit:** Android has its own way of packaging applications, I would suggest using it.

Comment: +1 For further protection ( and complexity ) use a code obfuscator

Answer (score 1):

Android doesn't use the Java runtime. I only uses Java as a source language, it runs a custom runtime with a custom bytecode format. You can [decompile the .dex byte code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249973/decompiling-dex-into-java-sourcecode), but not to Java source code, at least not at the time of this post.