# how to use DEXtoJar

Tags: decompiler

I find the solution to decompile a file dex to jar from this link https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar but i don't understand how to use it.

Comment: adding download link : https://sourceforge.net/projects/dex2jar/files/ project is moved.

Comment: to get only symbol information, just drag and drop the .dex file into your android studio

Answer (score 89):

Follow the below steps to do so_

> 1. Rename your APK file(e.g., *rename your APK file to .zip* Ex- **test.apk -> test.zip**) & extract resultant zip file.
> 2. Copy your *.dex file* in to *dex2jar* folder.
> 3. Run *setclasspath.bat*. This should be run because this data is used in the next step.
> 4. Go to Windows Command prompt, change the folder path to the path of your *dex2jar* folder  and run the command as follows:
>      **d2j-dex2jar.bat classes.dex**
> 5. enjoy!! Your jar file will be ready in the same folder with name **classes_dex2jar.jar**.

Hope this helps you and All reading this... :)

Comment: @Rupesh not able to find 'setclasspath.bat' location?

Comment: if you don't have `setclasspath.bat` you can just skeep part with it (works for me)

Answer (score 44):

1. Download dex2jar  https://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/downloads/list
2. Run dex2jar on apk `d2j-dex2jar.sh someApk.apk`
3. open jar file in JD GUI http://jd.benow.ca/

Follow this guide: https://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/wiki/UserGuide

--Update 10/11/2016--

Found this ClassyShark from Google's github pretty easy to view code from APK.

https://github.com/google/android-classyshark

// make sure that you downloaded release https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar/releases (for the ppl who coldnt find this link in /dex2jar/downloads/list

Comment: Where do you see this **d2j-dex2jar.sh**?  I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky , download the latest version of dex2jar (link: https://sourceforge.net/projects/dex2jar/) & you'll get both `bat` & `sh` versions of each script.

Comment: I still can not find the d2j-dex2jar.sh file. İt is really interesting.

Answer (score 43):

```
Step 1 extract the contents of dex2jar.*.*.zip file 
Step 2 copy your .dex file to the extracted directory
Step 3 execute dex2jar.bat <.dex filename> on windows, or ./dex2jar.sh <.dex filename> on linux
```

Comment: I'm using ubuntu and while running the 3rd command i'm getting an error: bash: ./dex2jar.sh:Permission denied , what's wrong happening here

Comment: you will need to specify read,write and execute permission, possibly you can write chmod 777 "directory name"

Comment: @kendrelaxman  i m also not getting 3rd point can u tell me how to do that ?

Comment: @kendrelaxman regarding the 3rd step what did you do? I'm using Windows. how should I execute it? cmd?

Comment: There is no such thing as **dex2jar.bat**

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky, make sure you do not clone, but download the release: https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar/releases

Answer (score 28):

Simple way

1. Rename your **test.apk** => **test.zip**
2. Extract test.zip then open that folder
3. Download [dex2jax](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dex2jar/files/latest/download?source=files) & Extract
4. Copy classes.dex file from test folder
5. Past to dex2jar Extracted folder
6. if use windows press **Alt** & **D** keys then type **cmd** press **Enter**(open to cmd)
7. run the command **d2j-dex2jar.bat classes.dex**
8. Download [JD-GUI](http://jd.benow.ca/)
9. Move classes-dex2jar.jar file to JD-GUI
10. Everything Done..

Answer (score 5):

1. old link

- the link http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/downloads/list is old, it will redirect to https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar

2. dex2jar syntax

- in https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar, you can see your expected usage/syntax:
- `sh d2j-dex2jar.sh -f ~/path/to/apk_to_decompile.apk`
- can convert from `apk` to `jar`.

3. want `dex` to `jar`

- if you have `dex` file (eg. using `FDex2` dump from a running android apk/app), then you can:
- `sh d2j-dex2jar.sh -f ~/path/to/dex_to_decompile.dex`
- can got the converted `jar` from `dex`.
- example:
- `/xxx/dex-tools-2.1-SNAPSHOT/d2j-dex2jar.sh -f com.huili.readingclub8825612.dex dex2jar com.huili.readingclub8825612.dex -> ./com.huili.readingclub8825612-dex2jar.jar`

4. want `jar` to `java src`

- if you continue want convert from `jar` to `java sourcecode`, then you, have multiple choice:
  * using `Jadx` directly convert `dex` to `java sourcecode`
  * first convert `dex` to `jar, second convert` jar`to`java sourcecode`

## Note

### how to got `d2j-dex2jar.sh`?

download from [dex2jar github release](https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar/releases), got [dex-tools-2.1-SNAPSHOT.zip](https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar/files/1867564/dex-tools-2.1-SNAPSHOT.zip), unzip then got

- you expected Linux's **`d2j-dex2jar.sh`**

  - and Windows's `d2j-dex2jar.bat`
  - and related other tools

    - `d2j-jar2dex.sh`
    - `d2j-dex2smali.sh`
    - `d2j-baksmali.sh`
    - `d2j-apk-sign.sh`
    - etc.

### what's the full process of convert `dex` to `java sourcecode` ?

you can refer my (crifan)'s **full** answer in another post: [android - decompiling DEX into Java sourcecode - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249973/decompiling-dex-into-java-sourcecode/55486175#55486175)

or refer my full tutorial (but written in **Chinese**): [安卓应用的安全和破解](https://book.crifan.org/books/android_app_security_crack/website/)

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is still looking for an easy way to decompile an APK (with resource decompiling), have a look at the tools I have created: https://github.com/dirkvranckaert/AndroidDecompiler

Just checkout the project locally and run the script as documented and you'll get all the resources and sources decompiled.

Comment: Great, this actually leverages dex2jar plus a few other tools.

Answer (score 4):

You can decompile your .apk files and download online.

http://www.javadecompilers.com/

Comment: This worked like a charm! Was even able to go straight from apk to source. Thanks for the share!

Answer (score 3):

1. Download latest dex2jar from here -> [dex2jar](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dex2jar/files/)
2. Run this command on linux -> sh d2j-dex2jar.sh classes.dex
3. Download java decompiler from here - > [JD-GUI](http://jd.benow.ca/)
4. Drag and drop the classes-dex2jar.jar file to JD-GUI

Comment: Where did you find **d2j-dex2jar.sh**?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: It will be inside the directory extracted from the zip of dex2jar

Comment: I couldn't find d2j-dex2jar.sh file as well after extracted zip.

Comment: @MustafaOlkun Download dex2jar-2.0.zip from above link. It is inside the folder. I just checked it.

Comment: @ParindaRajapaksha Thank you for comment. I can just find!

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for the version for windows get it from source forge:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/dex2jar/

It has the d2j-dex2jar.bat file you need

Comment: In this case, please post this as a comment instead of an answer if you think its helpful to give a hint towards answering the original question. Answers are for complete solutions to the original question only and not to share your own experience.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download Dex2jar and Extract it.
2. Go to Download path
         ./d2j-dex2jar.sh /path-to-your/someApk.apk
   if .sh is not compilable, update the permission: chmod a+x  d2j-dex2jar.sh.
3. It will generate .jar file.
4. Now use the jar with JD-GUI to decompile it

Answer (score 1):

Can be used as follow:

1. Download dex2jar [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dex2jar/) and extract it.
2. Download Java decompiler [here](http://java-decompiler.github.io/) (If you want to investigate **.class** file)
3. Get you release **.apk** file and change its extension with **.zip**
4. Extract .zip and find the **classes.dex** and **classes2.dex**
5. Paste these files into dex2jar folder where **.bat** file exist of dex2jar (normally names as **d2j-dex2jar**)
6. From dex2jar folder, open cmd [Shift+right click to see option to open cmd/power shell]
7. Type the command in cmd: `d2j-dex2jar release.apk`
8. You will get the .class file, open this file into Java Decompiler.

Answer (score 0):

After you extract the classes.dex file, just drag and drop it to d2j-dex2jar

Answer (score -1):

The below url is doing same as above answers. Instead of downloading some jar files and doing much activities, you can try to decompile by:

http://apk-deguard.com/