# How to decompile .smali files to xml files?

Tags: android, xml, decompiler, smali

I am decompiling an apk file to source code.I got all the class files but resource files are shown in smali format.How to convert this to xml files ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decompile .smali files on an APK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582824/decompile-smali-files-on-an-apk)

Comment: So its not possible to get xml files ??

Comment: no you can't. because they used proguard. if proguard not used, ofcourse you can get [all files](http://www.decompileandroid.com/)

Comment: smali has nothing to do with android's resource files. You can use apktool to recover the xml files.