# Add x86 support to an apk

Tags: android, x86

First of all I'm not an android dev

I have an apk which only supports arm.
I decompiled it with apk tool.
And now i have it as smali files.
Can this be compile with x86 abi support by building it again with gradle in android studio?

Or is there any other way to add x86 support to that apk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that depends on native code/libs used in your project, but generally you can build an x86 apk in Android Studio. there is no way for "migrating" arm APK to x86 (or any other) without sources and building whole up again. some clues HOWTO in [HERE](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis#gc) (`abiFilters 'x86'`) and/or [HERE](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split) (`include "x86"`)

Comment: `building whole up again` that's the thing I want to do but from a decompiled apk

Comment: if you have all needed sources then you probably may create new AS project, paste all data and build x86 version. looks like a lot of work with a lot of quirks and hidden settings, without an original project: tough one

Comment: I have only the decompiled smali files. how can it be used in AS on building the project.

Comment: they can't be, smali isn't a source. read [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582824/decompile-smali-files-on-an-apk)