# Is it possible to debug classes in a third-party Android application?

Tags: java, android, debugging, dex

I have an Android library that I distribute as a jar to third-parties who integrate it into their applications. A particular client is having a problem I wish to debug. Is it possible to rebuild their application into a form that I can debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try decompiling. [JavaDecompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/) can do a good job with a jar. All files, in JAR files, are displayed.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, but in this case while I distribute my code in a jar, it gets built into a Android application, so the resulting bytecode is Dalvik.

Comment: Ah, it looks like that tool doesn't support it directly, but dex2jar, the tool mentioned in another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249973/decompiling-dex-into-java-sourcecode) does support converting the dex into jar, then I could use the JavaDecompiler.

Comment: Good news, i hope it will get you where you wanna go :-)

Comment: The results from using a combination of dex2jar and the JavaDecompiler provide source that's good enough to get an idea of what the code is doing, but not code that compiles or is completely accurate. In my case it was good enough, so I'll go with this as the answer. Some people are using smali/baksmali to debug applications without the source, that that requires working at a lower level.