# proguard.cfg file missing

Tags: android, proguard

Reading the docs on proguard . . .
[android docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html)

I'm supposed to have a ProGuard.cfg as it says...
"When you create an Android project, a proguard.cfg file is automatically generated in the root directory of the project. "

If I google the issue there are answers all over the place most of them saying to modify a file that starts with a warning not to modify the file.

Are the docs out of date?  How to I get this enabled for release builds?
thanks, Gary

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you're using [ADT 17 or newer](http://tools.android.com/recent/proguardimprovements), the documentation is slightly inaccurate. The generated file is `proguard-project.txt` and will be in the root directory of your project.

To enable Proguard, you will need to ignore the "do not modify" warning in `project.properties` and uncomment the following line:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

The Android toolchain will sometimes make changes to `project.properties`, but your Proguard path will be preserved.

Comment: Thanks.  How can I examine my release .apk to tell if ProGuard did it's job?

Comment: Proguard produces a set of .txt files (e.g., `usage.txt`) in your project directory that tell you which files were removed, which ones were left untouched, etc. There's some helpful verification info in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153048/android-code-obfuscation-with-proguard-how-does-one-know-its-been-obfuscated

Comment: @acj uncomment this line, is all you have to do to enable Proguard?

Comment: @AlexAndro Yes. The Android tools should handle the rest.

Comment: I removed # from `project.properties` before the line you mentioned. I restarted the eclipse and rebuild my project but there is no `proguard-project.txt` in my root folder now.

Comment: @breceivemail : Your proguard txt file path might be missing in project.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the entire Proguard folder was missing at the location specified in the error. Make sure that the folder is present.