# Android - Proguard returned with error code 1

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard

I wanted my app to be progaurd protected. For this i went thru some tutorials, posts and at last from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512562/proguard-cfg-file-missing) post i came to know that i should only do this:

> If you're using ADT 17 or newer, the documentation is slightly inaccurate. The generated file is proguard-project.txt and will be in the root directory of your project.
>
> To enable Proguard, you will need to ignore the "do not modify" warning in project.properties and uncomment the following line:
>
> ```
> proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
> ```

After uncommeting the above suggested line i tried to export the unsigned application. But got an export error saying `progaurd returned error with code 1` . When i clicked the details button on the error dialog, i got the error log shown below:

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
Proguard Error 1 
Output: 
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars. 
Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [acra-

4.4.0.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF]) 
Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry 

[libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF]) 
Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [google-play-

services_lib.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF]) 
Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry 

[vpilibrary.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF]) 
Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry 

[abslibrary.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF]) 
java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\SURESH\AppData\Local\Temp

\android_6223056648746329994.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\SURESH\Desktop\ActionBarSherlock-

4.2.0\ABSlibrary\bin\abslibrary.jar] (Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream)) 
    at proguard.OutputWriter.writeOutput(OutputWriter.java:264) 
    at proguard.OutputWriter.execute(OutputWriter.java:160) 
    at proguard.ProGuard.writeOutput(ProGuard.java:372) 
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:153) 
    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492) 
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't read [C:\Users\SURESH\Desktop\ActionBarSherlock-

4.2.0\ABSlibrary\bin\abslibrary.jar] (Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream) 
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:230) 
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:200) 
    at proguard.OutputWriter.writeOutput(OutputWriter.java:253) 
    ... 4 more 
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream 
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:223) 
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:141) 
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:154) 
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.closeEntry(ZipInputStream.java:100) 
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipInputStream.java:78) 
    at proguard.io.JarReader.read(JarReader.java:58) 
    at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.readFiles(DirectoryPump.java:65) 
    at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.pumpDataEntries(DirectoryPump.java:53) 
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:226) 
    ... 6 more
```

Any idea why is this happening? am i correctly configuring progaurd or missing out steps?

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is listed in the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't read [C:\Users\SURESH\Desktop\ActionBarSherlock-4.2.0\ABSlibrary\bin\abslibrary.jar] (Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream)
...
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream 
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:223)
    ...
```

You should check the following:

- Is the file `abslibrary.jar` present at the given location?
- Is it a valid jar (can you open it with some unzipping tool)?
- Is it being written during the build process? If it somehow is being written asynchronously, it might still be incomplete when ProGuard reads it.

Comment: actually i got the above error only for the first time. When i tried it to export for the second time, it got exported normally and i continued with the signing process. After completing signing process i tried to test the app on a device and app got crashed immediately on launch. this is the logcat message on crash http://pastebin.com/TWbjsNp3

Comment: @suresh That's a different question. The field SILENT is accessed by reflection. You should preserve it with a -keep option. See the ProGuard manual.

Comment: I get the same error if my android app refers to another android library project when ProGuard processes.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by annotation -libraryjars about the jar that can't found.The document say is will not present jar,it will load the jar in run time.