# Exception while trying to configure proguard for obfuscation . Duplicate class definitions

Tags: android, security, proguard

I am trying to obfuscate my code using proguard . I am using google maps in my project .

But i am getting the following exceptions .

How to resolve ?

```
        Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
    Warning: class [bin/classes/com/google/android/gms/BuildConfig.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.google.android.gms.BuildConfig]
    Warning: class [bin/classes/com/google/android/gms/R$attr.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.google.android.gms.R$attr]
    Warning: class [bin/classes/com/google/android/gms/R$id.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.google.android.gms.R$id]
    Warning: class [bin/classes/com/google/android/gms/R$string.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.google.android.gms.R$string]
    Warning: class [bin/classes/com/google/android/gms/R$styleable.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.google.android.gms.R$styleable]
    Warning: class [bin/classes/com/google/android/gms/R.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.google.android.gms.R]
    Note: there were 1656 duplicate class definitions.
    Warning: there were 6 classes in incorrectly named files.
             You should make sure all file names correspond to their class names.
             The directory hierarchies must correspond to the package hierarchies.
             If you don't mind the mentioned classes not being written out,
             you could try your luck using the '-ignorewarnings' option.
    java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
        at proguard.InputReader.execute(InputReader.java:133)
        at proguard.ProGuard.readInput(ProGuard.java:196)
        at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:78)
        at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
    Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
    proguard.ParseException: Unexpected keyword 'names' in line 30 of file 'D:\redBus_Update_3\proguard-project.txt',
      included from argument number 4
        at proguard.ConfigurationParser.unknownAccessFlag(ConfigurationParser.java:1048)
        at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseClassSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:547)
        at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseKeepClassSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:490)
        at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:138)
        at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:484)
```

Please find the contents of the proguard file below .

I tried using ignore warnings options for those files as well

```
    # To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

-libraryjars D:\google-play-services_lib_en
-libraryjars D:\redBus_Update_3\libs\FlurryAgent.jar
-libraryjars D:\redBus_Update_3\libs\gson-2.2.2.jar
-libraryjars D:\redBus_Update_3\libs\bugsense-3.0.1.jar
-libraryjars D:\redBus_Update_3\libs\android-support-v4.jar

-keep class android.location.** { *; }

-keep public class com.google.android.maps.** {*;}
-keep public class com.google.android.maps.** {*;}
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.maps.** {*;}

-dontwarn com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint
-dontwarn com.google.android.maps.MapActivity
-dontwarn com.google.android.maps.MapView
-dontwarn com.google.android.maps.MapController 
-dontwarn com.google.android.maps.Overlay
```

Comment: You should post your proguard.cfg file to see what is the problem.

Comment: I have attached the content of the proguard file as well

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't specify any -libraryjars options in your proguard-project.txt. The standard build script automatically passes the libraries that it can find in the `libs` directory to ProGuard.

If you get any warnings about missing classes, even though the application works fine in debug mode, you should consider adding -dontwarn options for these classes (cfr. many related questions and answers on this site).

Comment: I don't think that's the issue . Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512562/proguard-cfg-file-missing

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently. My solution to it end up being that I just needed to clean the project, which lead me to a different error:

```
/gen already exists but is not a source folder. Convert to a source folder or rename it.
```

So I renamed it genX, which was then auto recreated, cleaned the project, tested it, then deleted genX.

Doing this solved my Proguard issues.