# Cannot find the proguard.cfg file eventhough it was renamed to proguard-project.txt?

Tags: android, proguard

Im trying to export my android project but after I click finish in the export wizard, it tells me that it cant find my proguard.cfg file. I read that proguard.cfg files dont exist anymore, they have been renamed to proguard-properties.txt and I have this file.

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: May be this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512562/proguard-cfg-file-missing link will help you

Comment: I followed that question but I get the error java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Clay (The system cannot find the file specified). It's weird because my folder in D is not called Clay, it's called Clay's Work

Comment: Are you exporting from Eclipse? Something in the build process is getting confused by the single quote in your directory name. You can try working from a different directory.

Comment: @EricLafortune That worked. Thanks alot for the answer, post it and ill accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Eclipse plugin invokes ProGuard through a script. With older versions of the plugin and/or ProGuard, you should avoid spaces or other special characters in your project path. Quotes can still be a problem.