# Unable to export my signed apk using proguard?

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

I am using eclipse version 22. There is no project.config file present in my project directory. This is the error i am getting project.config missing.How can i add it to my project?

Comment: Have you tried creating that file manually?

Comment: I don't know how to create that, can you link me to a tutorial.

Comment: It's as easy as creating a new text file, but instead of `.txt` extension, use `.config`.

Comment: What do i write in it.

Comment: Whatever you want (it should have something to do with [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/#manual/examples.html) though). :)

Comment: I hope this can help you, "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512562/proguard-cfg-file-missing"

Comment: Error: Can't read [C:\My Work\Android Projects\BigNumberCalculator\usr\local\java\android-sdk\platforms\android-9\android.jar] (No such file or directory) this is the error i am getting now. Can my projects be anywhere or in eclipse sdk extraction location.

Comment: I have read that question it did not work.

Comment: Its working now.It generated dump.txt etc. so it has worked i think.