# How to run Proguard in Intellij IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea, proguard

I'd like to run Proguard on my Android app whenever I compile with Intellij.  I've [uncommented the magic line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14514604/1397061) in `project.properties`, but the [proguard folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7153073/1397061) is not created when I compile my app, and exception stack traces are [not obfuscated](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#decoding).

What is the simplest way to run Proguard at every compile in Intellij IDEA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created under project settings an artifact with `run ProGuard` checked and then created a new configuration with the artifact instead of make