# How to encrypt and decrypt URL in java?

Tags: java, android, web-services, encryption, spring-security

I am working on an android project and securing my code from reverse engineering using **proguard**. I'm facing a serious issue my code is secure like 90% secure but issue is with my web services URL. I did save URL's path in separate class like

```
Public class key_Strings
{
public static url="https://www.google.co.uk";
}
```

and say i'm using this URL in my activity like :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String URL=key_Strings.url;

    }
}
```

after exporting my .APK file i did apply reverse engineering tools and then at the end i get this class with anonymous name but thing is that i get the URL something like:

```
this.h="https://www.google.co.uk";
```

i want to secure my URL so need help
Thanks

Comment: A url is essentially a String. Did you search SO for how to encrypt Strings?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220069/does-proguard-work-to-obfuscate-static-string-constants

Answer (score 0):

Use DexGuard as [recommended](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#encrypt) in ProGuard FAQ.

Answer (score -1):

Ok My problem is being solved thanks every one and here is the solution that click on my mind just modify my code and problem is solved

```
Public class key_Strings
{
public  url="https://www.google.co.uk";
}
```

and here is my activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 

    {
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            key_Strings key_Strings=new key_Strings();

            String URL=key_Strings.url;

        }
    }
```

thanks for every one.