# Key generation example for in-app purchases on android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

In the in-app purchase sample application in sdk\extras\google\play_billing, there is a comment as follows.

```
/* base64EncodedPublicKey should be YOUR APPLICATION'S PUBLIC KEY
         * (that you got from the Google Play developer console). This is not your
         * developer public key, it's the *app-specific* public key.
         *
         * Instead of just storing the entire literal string here embedded in the
         * program,  construct the key at runtime from pieces or
         * use bit manipulation (for example, XOR with some other string) to hide
         * the actual key.  The key itself is not secret information, but we don't
         * want to make it easy for an attacker to replace the public key with one
         * of their own and then fake messages from the server.
         */
```

Can some one help with me with an example to generate the key at **runtime from pieces or use bit manipulation**? That part is unclear to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means that you should not leave your key in a plain string constant because *probably* not even by obfuscating it can be hidden from the curious eyes...

So build the key from different pieces of strips as, for example, let´s suppose the key is "123456". You can have the same String by concatenating 1L + "23", then parsing it to Long, multiplying by 1000 and adding 456:

```
    Long longVal = 1L;
String code = longVal.toString() + "23";
longVal = Long.parseLong(code) * 1000L + 456;
```

In bytecode after compilation it´ll be a little twisted and, even by decompiling everything will look even uglier and hard to read. BTW. Maybe you can [bitwise](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) it a bit, also.

More info: [Protect string constant against reverse-engineering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435980/protect-string-constant-against-reverse-engineering)

Comment: Thanks, the keys are incredibly long, this is a very hard job

Comment: maybe just build a list or a map of parts of the code and go concatenating each one... just don´t leave the code in a plain String constant.