# What are .dex files in Android?

Tags: android, dex

I have some questions regarding **dex files**

- What is a `dex` file in Android?
- How does dex work for Android?
- How are they used in debugging an Android app?
- Are they similar to java class files?

I need specific information please help on this and any real examples are  welcome!

Comment: plz Saw this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249973/decompiling-dex-into-java-sourcecode

Comment: how to run them on device: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199863/how-to-execute-the-dex-file-in-android-with-command

Comment: Yes, they are similar to java .class files from one side. Java VM interprets .class files while Delvik VM or Android Run Time interprets .dex files.

Answer (score 274, accepted):

**About the .dex File:**

One of the most remarkable features of the `Dalvik Virtual Machine` (the workhorse under the Android system) is that it does not use Java bytecode. Instead, a homegrown format called DEX was introduced and not even the bytecode instructions are the same as Java bytecode instructions.

**Compiled Android application code file**

Android programs are compiled into `.dex` (Dalvik Executable) files, which are in turn zipped into a single `.apk` file on the device. `.dex` files can be created by automatically translating compiled applications written in the Java programming language.

**Dex file format:**

1. File Header
2. String Table
3. Class List
4. Field Table
5. Method Table
6. Class Definition Table
7. Field List
8. Method List
9. Code Header
10. Local Variable List

Android has documentation on the `Dalvik Executable Format` (**.dex** files). You can find out more over at the official docs: [Dex File Format](http://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format.html)

`.dex` files are similar to java class files, but they were run under the Dalvik Virtual Machine (DVM) on older Android versions, and compiled at install time on the device to native code with ART on newer Android versions.

You can `decompile` .dex using the `dexdump` tool which is provided in android-sdk.

There are also some **Reverse Engineering Techniques** to make a `jar file` or `java class file` from a `.dex` file.

Comment: My jar file contains some xml in assets folder. I want this to be a part of .dex
Any idea how to implement this ?

Comment: @AndroidGuy - Jar file doesn't contain any android resource package (/asset) you have to use Android Library Package for this.

Comment: How does it work on ART, on Android Lollipop? Which files are used there, and in which path? Some said it will take more space. Is it true? If so, how come? I mean, native code seems to always be much smaller than byte-code, and dex files are similar to byte-code in terms of how it works.

Comment: One important thing to note is that `dexdump` is not a decompiler but a disassembler

Answer (score 97):

`dex` file is a file that is executed on the Dalvik VM.

Dalvik VM includes several features for performance optimization, verification, and monitoring, one of which is **Dalvik Executable (DEX)**.

Java source code is compiled by the Java compiler into `.class` files. Then the `dx` (dexer) tool, part of the Android SDK processes the `.class` files into a file format called `DEX` that contains Dalvik byte code. The `dx` tool eliminates all the redundant information that is present in the classes. In `DEX` all the classes of the application are packed into one file. The following table provides comparison between code sizes for JVM jar files and the files processed by the `dex` tool.

The table compares code sizes for system libraries, web browser applications, and a general purpose application (alarm clock app). In all cases dex tool reduced size of the code by more than 50%.

[image]

In standard Java environments each class in Java code results in one `.class` file. That means, if the Java source code file has one public class and two anonymous classes, let’s say for event handling, then the java compiler will create total three `.class` files.

The compilation step is same on the Android platform, thus resulting in multiple `.class` files. But after `.class` files are generated, the “dx” tool is used to convert all `.class` files into a single `.dex`, or Dalvik Executable, file. It is the `.dex` file that is executed on the Dalvik VM. The `.dex` file has been optimized for memory usage and the design is primarily driven by sharing of data.

Comment: Good info. Just one thing to point out. Sometimes there will be multiple dex files because of  method invocation instruction number limit. This limit is 65k methods. In that case your code will not be inside a single file but in 2 or more but everything else applies still. Also since dynamic class loading is also available you can load code (again in dexed form) from files and thus code will be inside multiple dex files.

Answer (score 94):

```
.dex file
```

Compiled Android application code file.

Android programs are compiled into .dex (Dalvik Executable) files, which are in turn zipped into a single .apk file on the device. .dex files can be created automatically by Android, by translating the compiled applications written in the Java programming language.

Comment: My jar file contains some xml in assets folder. I want this to be a part of .dex
Any idea how to implement this ?