# How to execute the dex file in android with command?

Tags: android, dex

Can any body please share the method to execute the dex file in android with command?

This is just to understand.

Comment: Do you mean how to generate dex file using SDK from command-line?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Let's say you have a the following code in file HelloWorld.java:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

To run it on an android device:

```
javac HelloWorld.java
dx --dex --output=classes.dex HelloWorld.class
zip HelloWorld.zip classes.dex
adb push HelloWorld.zip /sdcard/
```

For GB or earlier, you should be able to simply do:

```
adb shell dalvikvm -cp /sdcard/HelloWorld.zip HelloWorld
```

For ICS+:

```
adb shell mkdir /sdcard/dalvik-cache
adb shell ANDROID_DATA=/sdcard dalvikvm -cp /sdcard/HelloWorld.zip HelloWorld
```

Comment: I was trying to print android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT. Fails with java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError. Is any of android.* available in any way?

Comment: @GenaBatsyan - please create a new question, with more details (code snippet, stack trace, etc.). Tag it with the dex tag, and I'll see it :)

Comment: Here we go :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32564192/error-accessing-android-api-when-running-a-java-program-directly-from-dex-archiv

Comment: You can also use `app_process` instead of `dalvikvm` (which is going to launch ART instead of Dalvik on the newer API's)

Comment: even "dalvikvm" is just a legacy command that actually launches ART, since lolipop.