# Can Android execute a classes.dex (or .jar converted from classes.dex) without a manifest, drawables, etc?

Tags: android, dalvik, dex

I have a bunch of DEX files but were not extracted from an APK by myself so I do not have the manifest, drawables, plus the rest of the resources/etc that are typically wrapped inside an APK. Is it possible to execute these in Android? I have tried dalvikvm to run the .dex itself as well as the .dex contained inside a .jar. I have also found what I believe to be the main activity to call but still no luck. Is this even possible?

Comment: While the answers below may be appropriate in a certain context, but yes it is still possible to load a dex file with a dex class loader and use the classes in it, as long as it is made for that purpose (i.e. a dex file that you created yourself to be used as such).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to run an Android application like that. It must be packaged into an apk with an AndroidManifest.xml, etc.

Using dalvikvm with a dex/jar from the terminal like what you describe only works for a `public void main(String[] args)` style command-line java application.

Comment: Thank you! I spent a lot of time trying to get it to work and was starting to think that it's just not possible.

Comment: Maybe this needs a new question.. would it be theoretically possible to build a manifest based on the information in a classes.dex, enough so that a functioning apk could be built and executed?

Comment: For most apps, the bulk of the application's UI is defined in XML.  None of that is baked into the classes.dex.

Answer (score 0):

You can run only a jar(contains a classes.dex) or a dex file in the command line mode.
dalvikvm works like the java in the command line.

Here is an Example: [How to execute the dex file in android with command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199863/how-to-execute-the-dex-file-in-android-with-command)

Answer (score -1):

Nope is not possible...just go through how it is done!!

[image]

For more details check out: http://www.alittlemadness.com/2010/06/07/understanding-the-android-build-process/