# How can I build an Android apk without Gradle on the command line?

Tags: android, gradle, build, apk

I wrote an Android app that uses no dependencies or modules, has a single activity, and has a single layout file.

How can I build an apk file of my app on the command line without using Gradle (or other "build systems" or "dependency management" software)?

Comment: If you don't like Gradle, you can look into another build system (e.g., Maven, Buck). If that's not the problem... what is the reason for avoiding Gradle?

Comment: I don't want a build system. I want to build.

Comment: Building an Android app [involves lots of work](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/build-workflow). The diagram on that page will help get you started in terms of the different tools and pieces that are involved.

Comment: related: just the dex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199863/how-to-execute-the-dex-file-in-android-with-command

Comment: I'm an iOS developer, after downloading Xcode, user could use it to create app directly. Almost all the gears are on belt once download is complete. But each time I use Android Studio, I was very confused. After download it, you has to wait that endless gradle sync. Why Google can't ship those gradle stuff with Android Studio release directly.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use the following steps to build your apk manually, if you don't want use ant/gralde to build. But you must have Android SDK installed at least.

- create `R.java` from `aapt`
- use `javac` to compile all java source to `*.class`
- use `d8` (or `dx` in older SDKs) to convert all `*.class` to `dex` file, e.g output is `classes.dex`
- create initial version of APK from assets, resources and `AndroidManfiest.mk`, e.g output is `MyApplication.apk.unaligned`
- use `aapt` to add `classes.dex` generated in step 3 to `MyApplication.apk.unaligned`
- use jarsigner to sign `MyApplication.apk.unaligned` with debug or release key
- use `zipalign` to align the final APK, e.g output is `MyApplication-debug.apk` or `MyApplication-release.apk` if signing with release key
- Done

I have created a sample script to do all the stuffs above, see [here](https://github.com/WanghongLin/miscellaneous/blob/master/tools/build-apk-manually.sh)

Actually, Some articles have discussed this topic, see the following links.

https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/233-how-to-build-apk-file-from-command-line

https://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/08/22/building-android-application-bundles-apks-by-hand/

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I wanted to know!  Nice shell scripting and thanks for the articles,  too.

Comment: I did this and it works, however when I run the app in the emulator I always get a warning:  "This app was built for an older version of Android and may not work properly." I made sure it's using the correct build-tools directory and the android.jar from the correct platform version folder. What else do I need to do?

Comment: @user3700562, make sure your AndroidManifest.xml has a correct [`android:minSdkVersion`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element) specified. Right now, you need to specify version 23 or higher for the warning to not show up.

Comment: I believe you want to use d8 now instead of dx. Per https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/02/the-path-to-dx-deprecation.html dx isn't shipped anymore with the SDK.

Answer (score 3):

Try this for building apps with support libraries from command line. https://github.com/HemanthJabalpuri/AndroidExplorer

Answer (score 3):

A while back I stumbled across this thread after getting frustrated with both Android Studio and Gradle. Inspired by the answer from **alijandro** and [this template from authmane512](https://github.com/authmane512/android-project-template/blob/master/build.sh), I wrote a series of scripts to compile an Android app (including with dependencies/packages) in Java or Kotlin without any external build system.

Link: https://github.com/jbendtsen/tiny-android-template

There is a little bit of DIY involved here, but given that it's the sort of stuff that something like Gradle would do for you, I would argue that it's useful to know. Besides, it's like *wayyyy* less slow, and you have a lot more control how your app gets assembled.

Answer (score 2):

**alijandro** gave a perfect answer. I managed to write **simple ANT script** that builds production APK with AdMob and without gradle usage. A couple useful comments:

1. If you want to obfuscate classes you have to jar the compiled classes (between `javac` and `dx` steps) and run `proguard` on it
2. For `AdMob` you have to extract the following jars from zip archives (like 
   `C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services-ads\10.2.6\play-services-ads-10.2.6.aar`):

   - play-services-ads-10.2.6.jar
   - play-services-ads-lite-10.2.6.jar
   - play-services-base-10.2.6.jar
   - play-services-basement-10.2.6.jar
   - play-services-clearcut-10.2.6.jar
   - play-services-gass-10.2.6.jar
   - play-services-tasks-10.2.6.jar

These archives should be passed in `javac` and `dx`

3. For `AdMob` there are several additional simple config steps as well

`Gradle` does a lot of mess with android projects, so own script looks like a singular solution for projects that are going to go into production

Comment: Would be nice to see that ANT script, if you still have it around.