# how to execute the baksmali.jar in an android device

Tags: android, adb, dex, smali, antimalware

For the purpose of developing an Anti-malware on Android, I need to have the `smali` representation of an APK.

I'm trying to execute the the `baksmali.jar` directly on the device. I asked the author of the tool [GitHub: Executing baksmali on an Android device](https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali/issues/496).

I followed the steps according to the post 
[Stack overflow: How to execute the dex file in android with command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199863/how-to-execute-the-dex-file-in-android-with-command)

1. I downloaded the v2.2b4 version
2. `dx --dex --output=classes.dex baksmali.jar` I used the `dx` tool from `android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2`
3. `zip baksmali.zip classes.dex`
4. `adb push baksmali.zip /sdcard/` I'm using a genymotion emulator `custom phone-4.4.4 API 19`
5. `adb shell mkdir /sdcard/dalvik-cache`
6. `adb shell ANDROID_DATA=/sdcard dalvikvm -cp /sdcard/baksmali.zip org.jf.baksmali.Main`

After that, I'm getting this error message `Unable to locate class 'org/jf/baksmali/Main'`
Precisely

```
Unable to locate class 'org/jf/baksmali/Main'
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jf/baksmali/Main
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.jf.baksmali.Main" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/sdcard/baksmali.zip"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
    ... 1 more
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: unable to open DEX file
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:296)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:80)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:59)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:263)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:230)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:112)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:48)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:38)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.createSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:116)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.access$000(ClassLoader.java:65)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$SystemClassLoader.<clinit>(ClassLoader.java:81)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:125)
        ... 1 more
```

I don't understand this error, the classe path is correct.

How can I fix this ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I downloaded the `v2.2b4 jar` from [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/JesusFreke/smali/downloads/)

Comment: Try using the classes.dex directly, instead of zipping it. `adb shell ANDROID_DATA=/sdcard dalvikvm -cp /sdcard/classes.dex org.jf.baksmali.Main`

Comment: the V2.1.3 of the jar is working, instead of `org.jf.baksmali.Main` it's `org.jf.baksmali.main`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After moving around, I finally found the solution to the following problem:

" execute the `baksmali.jar` in an android device, ideally the execution is launched by an application targeting another application."

So, lets say we wont to develop an application that is able to "baksmali" (disassemble) another application, without requiring any special permission.

These are the steps to get the job done:

- download the `baksmali.jar v1.2.3`
- add the `jar` to the `app/libs` directory of the android studio project
- right click on the `jar` and select the option "Add it as a Library"
  (use the "Project->project" view to see the `libs` directory, you may not see it in the "Project->android" view)
- you can use the `org.jf.baksmali.main.main`methode by passing the `CLI`arguments to that method using a `String[]`

Here is a helloWorld App illustrating the use cas:

[GitHub: Baksmali Hello world](https://github.com/MassyB/BaksmaliApp)

After launchig the application you should see folders in the `/data/data/com.example.bartman.baksmalihelloworld/<name_of_baksmali_output>`