# How to convert a piece of java code to smali?

Tags: java, smali

i have this java code:

```
    /* renamed from: ˏ */
    public void m332() {
        Context context = this.f242;
        int ˏ = hk.m2612(context, 1);
        int ˏ2 = hc.m2545(context, 1);
        if (ˏ != 1 || ˏ2 != 1) {
            Toast.makeText(context, this.f242.getResources().getString(R.string.tamper_alert), 1).show();
            this.f242.finish();
```

i want to convert this to smali code
how can i do this?
(i tried java2smali plugin but i failed)

Comment: re-write it in smali.

Comment: i am only java programmer

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199863/how-to-execute-the-dex-file-in-android-with-command for how to convert a java jar to a dex file. From there, it's a simple matter to run baksmali on the dex file.

Answer (score 0):

Use this [smalidea](https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali/wiki/smalidea) plugin if you're using IntelliJ IDEA/Android Studio