# What is dexopt ? (Android Shell Command)

Tags: android, shell, command, dexopt

What does the Android shell command `dexopt` do?

Where can I find a manual?

Comment: http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/dalvik/docs/dexopt.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26263071/3063884

Answer (score 2):

`dexopt` is a system-internal tool that is used to produce optimized [dex files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7750464/3063884).

The source code is available here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik-snapshot/+/gingerbread/dexopt/OptMain.c

Documentation is also [included with the source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik-snapshot/+/gingerbread/docs/dexopt.html); here's a human-readable version: http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/dalvik/docs/dexopt.html