# Running UiAutomatorTestcase in AndroidJunit Test Project

Tags: java, android, android-uiautomator

I'm actually trying to implement a simple test suite within an AndroidJunit Test project which uses the following class

- UiObject
- UiSelector
- UiAutomatorTestcase

to click and open the Messaging application on the Android Device and run it as AndroidJunit Test in Eclipse.

While running the code I'm get the following exception

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!

I don't understand where I'm going wrong. Please let me know whether we can run the UiAutomatorTestcase test suite using the AndroidJuint Test project or not.

Here is the sample code and the failure trace

```
public class UiautomatorTest extends
        ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyMainActivity> {

    UiAutomatorTestCase mUiAutomatorTestCase;

    public UiautomatorTest() {
        super(MyMainActivity.class);`enter code here`
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.setUp();
        mUiAutomatorTestCase = new UiAutomatorTestCase();
    }

    public void testToOpenMessageApp() throws UiObjectNotFoundException {
        UiObject message = new UiObject(
                new UiSelector().description("Messaging"));
        message.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();

        UiObject composeMessage = new UiObject(
                new UiSelector().description("compose"));
        composeMessage.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();

        UiObject typeMessage = new UiObject(
                new UiSelector().description("Type Message"));
        typeMessage.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
        mUiAutomatorTestCase.getUiDevice().pressHome();

    }

}
```

The stacktrace

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
at mypackagename.UiAutomatorTestCase.<init>(UiAutomatorTestCase.java:5)
at mypackagename..setUp(UiautomatorTest.java:25)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1584)
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace from logcat?

Comment: I had attached the failure trace

Answer (score 4):

You need to run the test on an android device. For this to work the code needs to be [dexed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750448/dex-file-in-android) before it can be run, etc. Read more [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html#builddeploy) on how to build your test for running on android.

Run the test like so

```
adb shell uiautomator runtest <JARS> -c <CLASSES> [options]
```

From the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/index.html).

> To run your testcases on the target device, you can use the adb shell
>   command to invoke the uiautomator tool.

Comment: I'm able to run the test suite with the procedure provided above. But my actual concern is to check whether we can run the Uiautomator juint test with default Android test project or not.

Comment: @RajeshSamson That should definitely be possible.

Answer (score 2):

Android 4.3 includes a way to interact with UIAutomation from Instrumentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html#getUiAutomation() and the topic is introduced at http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.3.html#Testing

This seems to be another flavour of UI Test Automation. I I'd like to know more about the interaction between 4.3's UIAutomation and UIAutomator http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/index.html

Answer (score 1):

As standard, UI Automator tests are compiled and built into a jar file, on a desktop computer, they are then deployed to the device by pushing the jar file to the device using adb. They are then run on the device, in the Android runtime by using `adb shell uiautomator ...` Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/363437/vidstige for correcting my earlier post which was inaccurate.

Probably the fastest way to help you get your tests running is for you to post your code as part of your question.

Update 22 July 2013
I have not seen anyone else trying to run the test cases directly on the device rather than building them following the approach Google (Android) document. It *might* be possible, however you may have to work hard to discover whether your approach is possible or viable. UIAutomator is distinct and separate from the Android InstrumentationTestCase framework. Instead it interacts with the GUI and has the advantage of being able to interact with a wide range of apps, including things like the inbuilt Settings UI on Android devices.

I'd suggest you start with the documented tutorial from the Android development site http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html and see if you can get that working. You'll want to use a device running Android 4.2 (or later for those of you reading this when newer versions of Android are released). Once you've got the tutorial working, I hope it'll be a good starting point to write UIAutomator tests for whatever app you're aiming to write automated tests for.

You're welcome to post another update.

Comment: actually, the UiAutomator tests _are_ run in the Android run time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like script with .sh

```
 ant build

 $youtSdkPath/platform-tools/adb  shell     rm /data/local/tmp/ProjectName.jar
 $youtSdkPath/platform-tools/adb  push  $pathProject/bin/ProjectName.jar /data/local/tmp/
 $youtSdkPath/platform-tools/adb  shell     uiautomator runtest ProjectName.jar -c ClassToTest
```

bash theScript.sh