# Error during compiling UIautomator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-uiautomator

I have started learning about UIAutomator in eclipse based on http://university.utest.com/android-ui-testing-uiautomatorviewer-and-uiautomator/. When I wrote a simple code like this:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiDevice;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObject;

import com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestCase;

import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiSelector;

import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObjectNotFoundException;

import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiScrollable;

import org.junit.Test;

public class test {



@Test
public void test() {
    fail("Not yet implemented");
    getUiDevice().pressHome();
}

}
```

I get error that getUIDevice() is undefined for the type test. How to improve this?

Comment: FYI, the documentation you're following is pretty out of date. I'd recommend reading the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html)

Comment: OK, thanks. During compilation code: `public class testClass extends UiAutomatorTestCase{


 @Test
 public void testWP() throws UiObjectNotFoundException {
  fail("Not yet implemented");
  getUiDevice().pressHome();
  
 }

}` i got failure and I do not understand why:`junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Exception in constructor: testWP (java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
 at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestCase.<init>(UiAutomatorTestCase.java:5)
 at testClass.<init>(testClass.java:14)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 

`

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run the test on your host machine. It needs to run on an Android device. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752860/running-uiautomatortestcase-in-androidjunit-test-project

Answer (score 0):

Your test class must extends `UiAutomatorTestCase`.