# How to generate a jar file for a java project and use the jar in an android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I am trying to generate a jar file for a java project and then references the jar file in an android project. As a test, I create a simple java project only containing the following class

```
package test;
public class Test {
public static void hello(){
    System.out.println();
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    hello();
}
```

}

I export this project an executable Jar file under Eclipse. Then I copy this jar file into the "libs" folder of an android project, so the jar file occurs in the private library and I **check** the box of private libary under the "Order and Export" tab. I reference the jar file by adding the following statement into the *onCreate()* of the main activity of the android project

```
  Test.hello(); //reference the jar file
```

However, when I run the Android project, I get the

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test.Test
```

error. The full error track trace is below

```
 10-17 23:14:52.976: E/AndroidRuntime(16725): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 10-17 23:14:52.976: E/AndroidRuntime(16725): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test.Test
 10-17 23:14:52.976: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):   at      
  com.skyhookwireless.samples.wpsapitest.WpsApiTest.onCreate(WpsApiTest.java:71)
 10-17 23:14:52.976: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):   at    
  android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
 10-17 23:14:52.976: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):   at 
 android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
 10-17 23:14:52.976: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):   at 
 android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
 10-17 23:14:52.976: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):   at 
 android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
 10-17 23:14:52.976: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):   at 
 android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
 10-17 23:14:52.976: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):   at 
 android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
 10-17 23:14:52.976: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):   at 
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 10-17 23:14:52.976: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):   at 
  android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  10-17 23:14:52.976: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):  at     
   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
    10-17 23:14:52.976: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):    at  
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   10-17 23:14:52.976: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):     at 
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  10-17 23:14:52.976: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):  at          
  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980) 
  10-17 23:14:52.976: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):  at  
  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
 10-17 23:14:52.976: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):   at    
    dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Attached are the screenshots of the order and export tab and the jars contained in each library.[image: the jars contained in each library][image: order and export tab]

Does anyone know how I can correct this?

I've read couple of posts (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247998/noclassdeffounderror-eclipse-and-android)) on this site regarding the NoClassDefFoundError and tried the solutions listed in comments or answers. But no one solves my problem in this simple scenario.

Comment: Did you follow the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html) on this topic? I'm using those guidelines with no problems.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace please ?

Comment: i've read the article you linked. but it only talks about android library projects and does not mention how to make java projects as libraries, does it?

Comment: Can you share screen shots of Java Build Path>Order and Export? Have you tried checked Android Dependencies?

Comment: tried to put gen before src, not helpful

Comment: i think this is a common use case, surprised that no applicable answer occurs yet

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by following steps , this is for making jar from android library project

```
$ cd your_project_path
$ android update project -p .
$ ant jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you import your Java project into Android workspace and then use it as a library in your Android project? This should resolve your issue.

Comment: I did. Makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible for the Dalvik VM to run Java bytecode. 
And also your Java JAR does not contain any .dex files, the classes inside it would not be found.

[See this answer for info on DEX format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27857615/4899193)

You could convert your Java JAR into an Android JAR. 
Or add your Java sources into your Android project, even referencing the same source files as your Java project...