# Android .properties file change values

Tags: java, android, inputstream, outputstream, properties-file

I have an android project and I'm using a custom .properties file, that I store in in a packet together with a class with which I can access it. While I run the programm I need to change some values of the .properties file but I can't access it as I don't know which is the Location it is stored in my device.

I thought about accessing to it by using `InputStream` and change the values like in java with an `OutputStream`, but while in `InputStream` there is the `getResourceAsStream` method in `OutputStream` there is not an opposite method in order to perform the action I want.

I have searched on the Internet, but the only solution I found is to move my .properties file into assets directory and get access to it using `AssetsManager`, which I don't want to!

I'm a newbie in android so any help will be welcomed !!

Answer (score 0):

You could put it in a directory in the external storage and then read it like a java.io.File:

```
File myProperties = new File( Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "myDir/myPorperties.properties");
```

obviously you could put the default properties file in assets and copy from asset to the external storage at the first app's run.

NB: you need this permissions in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I want to read it from where it is ! Secondly I want also to write in it !

Comment: why you can't move the file from where it is?

Comment: If moved it I should change the whole project ! I'm just trying to avoid it !

Comment: at least you could use your private directory:
/data/data/<package>/files/
where only your app have r/w permissions.
But you cannot modify a prop file inside the src directory because the content in src folder are stored in a [.dex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750448/dex-file-in-android) file inside the apk. In other words you are trying to modify a file inside a running-jar and this is not possible.