# What is dex in Gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, dex, dexoptions

What is the dex in Gradle or in Android?

In Gradle, what's the meaning of `dexoptions`?

Sometimes my project does not compile because of some dexerrors.
I need to activate ProGuard to compile my Android app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750448/dex-file-in-android

Answer (score 41, accepted):

### In the standard java world:

When you compile standard java code : the compiler produce *.class file. A *class file contains standard java bytecode that can be executed on a standard JVM.

### In the Android world:

It is different. You use the java language to write your code, but the compiler don't produce *.class files, it produce *.dex file. A `*.dex` file contains bytecode that can be executed on the Android Virtual Machine (dalvik) and this is not a standard Java Virtual Machine.

To be clear: a dex file in android is the equivalent of class in standard java.

So [`dexoptions` is a *gradle object*](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DexOptions.html) where some options to configure this *java-code-to-android-bytecode* transformation are defined. The options configured via this object are :

- targetAPILevel
- force-jumbo mode (when enabled it allows a larger number of strings in the dex files)

To enable `jumboMode`  :

```
android {
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for the explanation ! And what about the ART vm ? Is it still .dex files ?
The dex seems to have a limited size when compiling java code. Sometimes I get an dexError, something like "there are too much classes to be compiling in 65535 bits". I need to activate proguard even in debug mode, and I cannot debug my app (breakpoints don't stop because of obfuscation)
Do you have an advice for me ?

Comment: @psv see my edit about jumbo mode and try that. It's probable that activating proguard reduce the amount of code in your dex files