# multiple dex files define landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes

Tags: java, android

The moment I added the android support annotations to my dependencies

`compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:20.0.0'`

I got this error:

> Error Code:
>       2   Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)

**build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:20.0.0'
}
```

Anybody else experienced this issue? I have tried the solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059719/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define).

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The problem is that `android-support-annotations.jar` used to be a separate library containing the android annotations, but for some reason these annotations are already included in recent versions of the `android-support-v4.jar` file.

Deleting the annotations jar solved the issue.

Comment: problem may happen when you include two `android-support-v4.jar` jar files with different version into your project

Comment: @ahmedhamdy including v4.jar  with    different  SHA  key  throws a different   error  and  not  leads to a  dex issue

Comment: @mister-smith how can i remove one of them? i'm stuck with this issue :(

Comment: this solved it for me. if you're working on a cordova app, delete the mentioned file from /platforms/android/libs/

Comment: Deleted the annotations jar. But still getting the error.

Comment: I have a set of libraries as modules but annotation.jar is found nowhere in any of it's gradle file.What to do now?

Comment: this has helped so many times now! thanks for your answer @Mister Smith

Answer (score 34):

Build->clean Project ,and it worked

Comment: I'm not sure how (I tried this a few times before with no results), but after I tried again (after seeing this comment) .. MIRACLE!! :D

Comment: my life is going to get a whole lot easier once I start remembering to try this first any time I have a gradle issue

Comment: It worked when I run 'clean' task which deletes /app/build folder.

Answer (score 23):

I deleted the android-support-v4.jar and it worked.

Comment: I unchecked it from Java Build Path > Libraries. (Y). Works like charm

Answer (score 10):

If this is cordova / ionic project this worked for me

add these line to build.gradle under platforms/android after line number 22 i.e after **apply plugin: 'android'**

```
configurations {
   all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me using the "cordova-plugin-googleplus" and "phonegap-facebook-plugin" plugins. You save my day thanks!

Comment: I was trying to install cordova-plugin-document-viewer and this solution worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Solved this exact issue in a Cordova project that used the facebook plugin.  I was able to successfully build by commenting out this line from `platforms\android\project.properties`, as shown:

```
# cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4:+
```

And by commenting out this line from `platforms\android\build.gradle`, as shown:

```
// compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+"
```

Then doing the build.  The problem started when I installed (katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) which added these lines, but it created a conflict since the library it was adding to the build was already part of the facebook plugin build.

Comment: Worked for me too, I'm also using *cordova-plugin-local-notifications*. Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

As other users said, the first elements to troubleshoot are dependencies. Although, sometimes you can struggle for hours and you don't find any problem so you can focus on the *build process* instead.

Changing [the way in which the `.dex` files are produced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24224186/what-is-dex-in-gradle) sometimes solves the problem. You can go through these steps:

- Open your **Build.gradle (app)**  file
- Search for the task **dexOptions**
- Change it to:

  ```
  dexOptions {
    incremental false 
  }
  ```

If you don't find the task in your file then you can add it.

Answer (score 2):

For me the reason was the new data-binding lib

```
com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc2
```

it somehow used a conflicting version of the annotations lib, which I could not force with

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force group: 'com.android.support', name: 'support-v4', version: '23.1.0'
        force group: 'com.android.support', name: 'appcompat-v7', version: '23.1.0'
        force group: 'com.android.support', name: 'support-annotations', version: '23.1.0'
    }
}
```

but the new `rc3` and `rc4` versions seem to have fixed it, so just use those versions

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem , but i deleted build files from the build folder

projectname/app/build

and it removed all the related error. "can't clean the project" and also "dex errow with $anim"

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this issue. The reason was that I included the android support library 19.0.0 as a dependency, but 19.1.0 is required. [See here for more information](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/support-annotations)

So it has to be

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:20.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you import `AppCompat` as a library project and you also have `android-support-annotations.jar` in libs elsewhere, make sure to import everywhere `AppCompat` library only (it already includes this annotations lib). Then delete all `android-support-annotations.jar` to avoid merging multiple versions of this library.

Comment: I was having this same problem on android studio however I didn't have a support-annotations in my build.gradle. Cleaning the project didn't fix it. I found that despite not having the android-support-annotations.jar in my app build.gradle it was still in my app.iml. Once I deleted the android-support-annotations.jar from my app.iml (and cleaned the project again for good measure). This fixed my problem completely

Answer (score 1):

Updating Android SDK Tools fixed it for me, now it just sees the copy in `android-support-v4.jar`.

I had the same problem when using ant, and the annotations library was being included automatically by an outdated `sdk.dir/tools/ant/build.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

Clean project works as a temporary fix, but the issue will reappear on next compilation error.

To fix more reliably, I had to update the dependency to android `support-v4` to `com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Put in your **build.gradle** the dependency of support-annotations according with your compileSdkVersion. For instance: A project with the **compileSdkVersion 25** you can put the following dependence:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.1'
```

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a file called `cache.xml` under `/build/intermediates/dex-cache/cache.xml` in the root project folder. I deleted this file, rebuild the project and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the android-support-v4.jar and it worked.

Explain - android-support-v4.jar is conflicting with my other .jar files of project\libs files ** specially when you are running with java 8 on AS.

Answer (score 0):

Put android-support-v4.jar in your libs folder in eclipse. Clean and build the project. It will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason that messages such as these can come up in Android Studio when building and launching can be the cause of application tags in your libraries.

If you have several Android Library projects that you imported as modules.  Go into those projects and remove the `<application> ... </application>` tags and everything between them.  These can cause issues in the build process along with the support library issues already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

From /platforms/android/libs/
delete android-support-v4.jar.
It works for me.