# Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. UNLESS I clean project first

Tags: java, android, build

I'm a little new to Android Studio and my project has been going well until I added in SpongeyCastle as a dependency. Then I started getting some build errors.

At first I thought I had some conflict, but after trying many combinations I discovered that it was more about having to clean my project before every build otherwise I'd get an Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. error.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this using the Android Studio IDE? I keep thinking there must still be some dependency issues here. Maybe something is in the build file...

These are my packages:

```
compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.80.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.0.0'
compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.15'
compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13'
compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.7'
compile 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:4.0.0.Final'
compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.51.0.0'
compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.51.0.0'
```

And this is the error code:

```
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","position":{},"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;","position":{},"original":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)"}


 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Thanks in advance for pointers. I'll be continuing to search for other's with the same error and if I find the solution I'll return to detail.

Answer (score 0):

check if u have properly added last library. 
Just remove last 0 from spongycastle. Also make sure, u have proper versions of appcompat and v4 libraries.

You shuold also read this topic [dex lvl 2 output error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26342444/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-annotation-animres)

Cheers,