# where does android-support-annotations.jar exists ? what it is path?

Tags: android

I downloaded the latest `android-support-v4.jar` and added it the library folder but I had this error

```
 Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
```

in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26342444/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-annotation-animres) they said I have to delete `android-support-annotations.jar` where does it exists it to delete it

Comment: still eclipse? Stop using it and use Android studio with compile dependences and save your time :)

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski yes the stupid eclipse , I cannot simple move now to android studio , I just need to finish the project then I am pretty sure to dump eclipse