# Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes Error.How to find repeated references?

Tags: android, android-studio

- Error

---

```
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I find the relevant answers [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26342444/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-annotation-animres), but the Android Studio Android - support - how to find repeat in v4 package?

- My build.gradle file

---

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
    compile 'com.orhanobut:logger:1.11'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.6'
    compile(name: 'MiotService-release', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'plug_common-release', ext: 'aar')
    //AndroidViewAnimations
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
}
```

- My libs folder

---

```
ite-orm-1.5.jar
litecommon1.0.0.jar
MiotService-release.aar
plug_common-release.aar
qiniu-android-sdk-7.0.6.jar
zxing-core-3.2.0.jar
```

- OR

Do you have other solution?Please tell me.

Comment: Have you tried  `multidex enabled true`

Comment: @Soham Thank you very much, solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in your `build.gradle` inside `andoid{ }`:

```
defaultConfig { 
    multiDexEnabled true 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, solve my problem.Your answer is very detailed