# Error in android studio \Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Hello i get the error while trying to run my app it was an app that used to work(while it was in eclipse ) been trying to make it work in android studio after several errors now this1 hit me and cant figure out anything . Thank You for  help.

EDİT
No error when i build the app it comes when  i try to run the app.

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

Build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1"
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so basicly after removing every compile part it worked when only this left

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

}

changed dependices to this

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `android_support_annotations.jar` file, as recommended at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26713987/1476989). Your problem is caused by the annotations jar being included by default in the Android support library so there are now two copies.

You could also try temporarily removing `compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+"` from your build.gradle and see if that makes a difference.

(The solution was to remove all but `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'` in the dependencies).

Comment: from where i need to delete this? i didn't find it in build.gradle

Comment: Please include your build.gradle in the question, it will help.

Comment: Updated. Try `Build->Clean project` as well, just in case!

Comment: i dont get any errors when i clean project everything is fine this comes when i run the app

Comment: Did you remove `compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+"`?

Comment: done that and some other stuff check code again edited there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97717/discussion-between-wince-and-pgmann).