# AndroidStudio error that my app isn't compatible with Java 7

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Here is my Gradle build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "problemio.com.problemionew"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

My application compiled ok, but when I tried to run it, I got this error:

[image]

Any thoughts on what is going wrong here? My machine is set up for Java 6. When I tried to upgrade to Java 7 I got some errors so I had to revert to Java 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is due to problem in compilation which usually related to duplicated libraries or too many methods and classes. I guess that you are including google play services in you gradle . Try to use specific sub library from here https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup.

Comment: I got rid of android-support-v4.jar from my own lib files and it got rid of the error. Do you know if that might cause problems later? What does that library do? :)

Answer (score 0):

This error

> This error about for uses and give referance same classes.Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26342444/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-annotation-animres/26713987#26713987)

Comment: That link said that getting rid of the annotations jar solves the issues, but I don't have that jar :)

Comment: Thats Look here  "The problem is that android-support-annotations.jar used to be a separate library containing the android annotations, but for some reason these annotations are already included in recent versions of the android-support-v4.jar file."