# Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzpo

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

My code was working fine and build app fine and then i suddenly get an error after updating below given libraries from Android SDK Manager

Extra > Google Play Services

Extra > Google Repository

I have implemented both [cordova plugin googlefit](https://github.com/2dvisio/cordova-plugin-googlefit) and plugin [cordova plugin healthkit](https://github.com/dariosalvi78/cordova-plugin-health)

Dependencies into build.gradle file

dependencies {

```
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    debugCompile project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug")

    releaseCompile project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release")

    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:9.4.0"

    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0+"
```

}

I already tried android platform remove and add it again

I cannot able to build app using this command

> ionic build android

[image]

Comment: this happen when you include too much methods in a android project. You can add `multiDexEnabled:true` to your build.gradle but isn't the best solution. You should remove `play-services:7.5.0+` and add only what you need (for example: `play-services-fitness`)

Comment: can you try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26342444/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-annotation-animres/35146779#35146779

Answer (score 0):

Add this in you app build.gradle defaultConfig section

```
multiDexEnabled true
```