# how can I use Android dexOptions?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

What are the meaning of the dexOptions.incremental, etc.
Any body can explain them to me.

```
dex options

android {
    dexOptions {
        incremental false
        preDexLibraries = false
        jumboMode = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
    }
}
This affects all tasks using dex.
```

Comment: FYI, `preDexLibraries` setting should be set to false on CI server.

Comment: Why we should set preDexLibraries to false for CI server?

Answer (score 31):

> #### `boolean incremental`
>
> Whether to enable the incremental mode for dx. This has many limitations and may not work. Use carefully.
>
> #### `String javaMaxHeapSize`
>
> Sets the -JXmx* value when calling dx. Format should follow the 1024M pattern.
>
> #### `boolean jumboMode`
>
> Enable jumbo mode in dx (--force-jumbo).
>
> #### `boolean preDexLibraries`
>
> Whether to pre-dex libraries. This can improve incremental builds, but clean builds may be slower.

These can be found here:
http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DexOptions.html

Comment: Check https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build.html#dex_options for latest info, for example, using `javaMaxHeapSize` is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

set `incremental` to `true`.

This is experimental feature that is disabled by default. However you can enable it. I personally didn't noticed any changes in term of speed (if it affect the speed).

More explanation can be found there https://stackoverflow.com/a/24224385/513413.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "12g"
}

afterEvaluate {
    tasks.matching {
      it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
      if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
          dx.additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex']
      } else {
          dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
      }
    }
}
```