# Why project doesn't compile on Android Studio 1.5.1?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Previously, there were no problems. I put a fresh Android Studio 1.5.1 for OS X 10.11 and gives this error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:android_tools:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:android_tools:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:android_tools:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:android_tools:compileLint
:android_tools:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:android_tools:checkReleaseManifest
:android_tools:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:android_tools:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:android_tools:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:android_tools:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:android_tools:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:android_tools:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
:android_tools:prepareReleaseDependencies
:android_tools:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:android_tools:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:android_tools:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:android_tools:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:android_tools:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:android_tools:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:android_tools:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:android_tools:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:android_tools:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:android_tools:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:android_tools:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:android_tools:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:android_tools:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:android_tools:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:android_tools:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:android_tools:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:android_tools:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:android_tools:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:android_tools:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:android_tools:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:android_tools:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:android_tools:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:android_tools:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:compileLint
:download_manager:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:checkReleaseManifest
:download_manager:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:prepareReleaseDependencies
:download_manager:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:download_manager:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:media_webbrowser:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:media_webbrowser:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:media_webbrowser:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:media_webbrowser:compileLint
:media_webbrowser:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:media_webbrowser:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:media_webbrowser:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:media_webbrowser:checkReleaseManifest
:media_webbrowser:prepareReleaseDependencies
:media_webbrowser:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:media_webbrowser:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:media_webbrowser:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:media_webbrowser:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:media_webbrowser:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:media_webbrowser:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:media_webbrowser:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:media_webbrowser:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:media_webbrowser:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:media_webbrowser:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:media_webbrowser:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:media_webbrowser:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:media_webbrowser:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:media_webbrowser:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:media_webbrowser:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:media_webbrowser:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:media_webbrowser:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:media_webbrowser:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:media_webbrowser:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareAndroidavdownloaderAndroid_toolsUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareAndroidavdownloaderDownload_managerUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareAndroidavdownloaderMedia_webbrowserUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
Uncaught translation error: com.android.dex.util.ExceptionWithContext
1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 36.102 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

app build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.xxx.xxx'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 23
        versionName '2.5'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental = true;
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':download_manager')
    compile project(':media_webbrowser')
    compile project(':android_tools')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
}
```

android_tools build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

download_manager build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

media_webbrowser build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Many have tried to solve the problem. Nothing helps. Tell me what could be wrong?

=============

**I found a place where there is an error** (in module media_webbrowser).
An error at this point, when passed into the method of the new object interface: http://pastebin.com/jpUBznZ5

When passing null then there is no error: http://pastebin.com/Ewi7jz0q

============

### Problem was solved by installing jdk8 instead of jdk7

Comment: it seems like you might be over the dex limit, try compiling the multidex library and enable multidex

Comment: Post gradles of your modules: download_manager, media_webbrowser, android_tools.

Comment: @Sufian updated question (gradles of modules: download_manager, media_webbrowser, android_tools)

Comment: Not sure if it is the case. Always keep same buildToolsVersion. Replace `buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'` with `buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'` in all files. If no success, try [switching to multidex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library).

Comment: @Sufian I found a place where there is an error (question updated)

Comment: @alex-v Is the `LicenseManager` from Android SDK? Never used it. I guess you have to read its API.

Comment: @Sufian It is my class. Problem was solved by installing jdk8 instead of jdk7.

Comment: @alex-v post it as answer and mark it. Really weird error by Gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by installing jdk8 instead of jdk7

Answer (score 3):

remove `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'` from build gradle file and try again

Because you have to use full Google play service lib or separate parts of Google play service. use one of them.

below is used full Google play service libs

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

so if you are using separate portion of Google play service( like `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0`) then no need to add that.

**that's why your app dex size increase [Over 65K Methods](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/building/multidex.html)**

---

From [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

**Selectively compiling APIs into your executable**

> In versions of Google Play services prior to 6.5, you had to compile
>   the entire package of APIs into your app. In some cases, doing so made
>   it more difficult to keep the number of methods in your app (including
>   framework APIs, library methods, and your own code) under the 65,536
>   limit.
>
> From version 6.5, you can instead selectively compile Google Play
>   service APIs into your app. For example, to include only the Google
>   Fit and Android Wear APIs, replace the following line in your
>   build.gradle file:
>
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0' with these lines:
>
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.4.0' compile
>   'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0'

Comment: @alex-v try clean build. I really believe the solution suggested should really work.

Comment: The error stems from the fact that you used in the project more than 65k methods

Comment: Leaving only the line compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
and it did not help. Tried clean build.

Comment: @AndroidAndroid How to fix it?

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar updated question (full gradle console messages and fixed build.gradle)

Comment: @alex-v: remove this compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0' and use separate module com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0 whatever you have used previous.again try rebuild & clean

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar Maybe the problem is that the source code of the project is very large? And it must be solved in another way?

Comment: Clean and rebuid did not help

Comment: @alex-v: may be its possible if your app have lost of methods more then 65k or your app + Google play service >= 65k??

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar I found a place where there is an error (question updated)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're seeing this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33277193/processexception-org-gradle-process-internal-execexception-finished-with-non-ze)?

I'll copy the solution from that post here, just in case the link breaks in the future.

If you compile with "--info --debug" and notice an out-of-memory error, adding this block to gradle.build should resolve it.

```
android {
    dexOptions {
        incremental = true;
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" // 2g should be also OK
    }
}
```

Comment: Added this solution to app build.grudle, but still a compilation error: failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug' (updated question)

Comment: I found a place where there is an error (question updated)

Comment: Glad you fixed it, and thanks for letting us know what the solution was in the end.