# error at runtime in gradle

Tags: android, build.gradle

I have some problem in my application at run time.it giving the below error.

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.>
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 2

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.0-rc1'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.0-rc1'
// optional features
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.0-rc1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson-parent:2.6.1'

    }
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34992627/why-project-doesnt-compile-on-android-studio-1-5-1?noredirect=1#comment57748945_34992627) seems very similar. He fixed the problem by installing JDK 8 (previously he was using JDK 7). Did it work in your case?

Comment: Use gradlew assemble --info to get more info about the error.