# What is the purpose of jumboMode in dexOptions for a Gradle build?

Tags: android, gradle

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24224385/1176435)  it allows a larger number of strings in the dex files but I don't really understand what it means and the impact on builds.

Answer (score 5):

> Jumbo mode pertains to the number of strings that can be referenced in
>   a DEX file, which by default are indexed using 16 bit wide integers.
>   Therefore, if your application encodes more than 2^16 strings, the dx
>   tool will fail as well. For string references however, there is a
>   remedy: DEX supports “jumbo opcodes” which allow for 32 bit wide
>   string references. The jumboMode flag in an Android Gradle build
>   script enables this mode, allowing up to 2^32 strings to be
>   referenced.

What this means is if you have more than 2^16 references in your dex files, you can use `jumboMode` to accommodate for this by allowing up to 2^32 references. This is done by forcing the byte code to always use "jumbo strings" (2^32) references to help avoid issues when merging dex files.

Note: this does NOT have anything to do with the number of method references, so this mode doesn't solve when your dex file has more than 64k methods.

Source: https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/congratulations-you-have-a-lot-of-code-remedying-androids-method-limit-part-1

In my experiences, this shouldn't have any noticeable impact on builds other than a potential increase in build time.

Answer (score 4):

When you compile your code in android, your java code will be compiled into .dex file.

There is a restriction for number of strings that can exist in the dex file. By enabling **jumboMode**, you increase the number of strings that can exist in your dex file.

**jumboMode option is true since Gradle 2.1.0 so you dont have to worry about it**.