# Unable to merge dex app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-gradle-plugin

I'm able to clean and rebuild the project files but I couldn't run the application as it throws one RuntimeException.

this is my error :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

this is my gradle :

```
/*
 * Copyright © 2018 Quillbook. All rights reserved
 */

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dumpcoders.danielcruise.quillbook"
        minSdkVersion 17
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'

}
dexOptions {

    jumboMode true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"

}
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.15@aar') { transitive = true }
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.6.15'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider:2.6.15'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.6.15'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.6.15'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobileanalytics:2.6.15'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.15'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-sns:2.6.15'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-sqs:2.6.15'
    api 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-apigateway-core:2.6.15'
}
```

I've implemented all the AWS libs which is required for my project, what i'm trying to do here is connect to AWS!

Comment: try to Exclude group form all aws dependencies  exclude group: 'commons-io', module: 'commons-io'`

Comment: I excluded like this implementation  ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.6.15'){exclude group:'commons-io',module:'commons-io'}  whether is it correct??

Comment: Yeah it right . see if it works . If not please see the detailed message about build failed .

Comment: it didn't work man...

Comment: Do you have `multiDexEnabled` enabled ? If not then enable the `multiDex` first . I can see it in your `build.gradle` but have initilize it in Application class ?

Comment: No... How to initialize it in application class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: 
Tried your gradle config and worked flawlessly. but main reason of problem lies in

```
dexOptions {
    jumboMode true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

more about the [jumboMode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32067223/what-is-the-purpose-of-jumbomode-in-dexoptions-for-a-gradle-build)

Comment: Not worked for me... in the event log it says : Sources not found: Sources for 'aws-android-sdk-apigateway-core-2.6.15.jar' not found

Comment: Messages Gradle Build : Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Comment: I did everything I could @tatocaster

Comment: I tried the same gradle config, even without the multidex and works without a problem. Try to invalidate Android Studio cache and try again. I tried with/without `jumboMode` but the same effect, build is successful.

Comment: I invalidated and restarted android studio and again it's the same.... are you now saying to remove the jumbo mode in multidex?

Comment: in both cases, your gradle config worked for me. Try to remove `dexOptions` object and clean/rebuild from the scratch.  It seems there is not only 1 correct way to solve this problem

Comment: Yeah !! ..... Thanks a ton Man it worked ... I've been looking for the solution since 8 hours. You saved my day! @tatocaster

Comment: Good to know. I will edit answer please accept it or upvote at least. good luck