# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:buildInfo Debug Loader'

Tags: android, build.gradle

I updated few days ago to Android Studio 2.0 and everything worked fine, but today when I tried to compile the project, I received the following error in the `Logcat`:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:buildInfoDebugLoader'.
>
> Exception while doing past iteration backup : Source \app\build\intermediates\builds\debug\184802777347678\classes.dex and destination \app\build\intermediates\builds\debug\184802777347678\classes.dex must be different

The error tells me that the same `.dex`must be different, so I'm quite confused. How could I solve it?

Comment: anybody looking for more info on what .dex file is go here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750448/dex-file-in-android

Comment: Build -> Clean Project should solve the issue

Answer (score 54, accepted):

1. **Clean Your project.**
2. And try to **rebuild** it.

If you did it then enable mutidex in app base build.gradle file.

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

Answer (score 6):

Just add below line in your app Gradle dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

and then below line in defaultConfig

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

Answer (score 5):

The way I solved the problem was by just deleting the file!

Comment: that did the job for me, Thanks! better then changing Gradle

Comment: Which file should delete?

Answer (score 2):

just go and delete the build folder in your app folder. invalidate cache and clean your project then Rebuild...

Answer (score 1):

I am using Android Studio 2.2.1 and had the same error. I resolved this by deleting the folder containing the classes.dex file. In my case it was in the 32129143802723 folder from C:\Users\ME\AndroidStudioProjects\myApp\app\build\intermediates\builds\debug\32129143802723\classes.dex.

From the menu bar I went to File the selected Invalidate Caches/Restart... Then Invalidate and Restart option.

That fixed the issue. The error was gone and I was able to launch the app. Hopes this helps.

Answer (score 1):

So I just cleared the data on the app installed on the phone, and then uninstalled the app. Next time I ran it, it worked without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

You just Disable the antivirus 
make sure it will help you!

then , click clean project and Rebuild it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it renaming folder "build" inside my project folder. When you build again, android studio creates a new build folder.

Answer (score 0):

I just click on Build and on the drop down, click clean project, this fixes it very quickly

Answer (score 0):

The only thing which worked for me `flutter clean` on command line. It does similar to `./gradlew clean`

Answer (score 0):

Try invalidating and restarting caches in android studio. File > Invalidate Caches / Restart