# Where is APK java file?

Tags: java, zip, apk, unzip

I have recently become interested in changing an APK files extension to .ZIP. I began looking through them. I noticed that there were no .java or .class files. I do have hidden files enabled, so it cant be that. I am wondering:

How does the app function if the java is not there?[image: File contents of the apk/zip]

The zip file can be downloaded from here. (It's down right now. My dad is doing work with our WiFi.

http://71.204.114.18/Tyler/app.zip

(If the file is not there then I probably took it down. A few days or weeks, maybe months has probably passed)

Comment: Wow. some people I can't even trust with a link to my server. ClickMe.html and Virus.bat? I mean come on. My server is hosted on linux, not windows. and I downloaded the the .bat file as a text file on my computer(this one IS windows). shutdown -p. and what was going to make me run this Virus.bat?

Comment: Wow. I was really mad when I wrote that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android programs are compiled into `.dex` (Dalvik Executable) files. File `classes.dex` contains app code.

You can read more on: [Dalvik Executable format](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format.html) and [StackOverflow question about .dex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750448/dex-file-in-android)